# MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Which is better, MySQL or MySQLi? And why? Which should I use?

I mean better not just in terms of performance, but any other relevant feature.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you have a look at [MySQL Improved Extension Overview](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php), it should tell you everything you need to know about the differences between the two.

The main useful features are:

- an Object-oriented interface
- support for prepared statements
- support for multiple statements
- support for transactions
- enhanced debugging capabilities
- embedded server support.

Comment: yeah, the best thing is that mysqli supports prepared statements

Comment: It should also be noted that MySQLi only works with MySQL 5+. This isn't really relevant anymore, but when MySQLi came out, MySQL 4 was still the standard. This is part of the reason the extensions are separate, the old MySQL driver staying there for compatibility purposes.

Comment: It's worth noting that things have changed a lot in six years. `mysql_*()` is now deprecated and __will be removed__ soon. You shouldn't use it for new code.

Comment: Which should we choose with less CPU and RAM?

Comment: See Gordon's answer below. The old mysql extension is no longer supported so you'll be better of using mysqli extension anyway.

Comment: @user1864610 It was removed with PHP 7

Answer (score 71):

There is a manual page dedicated to help choosing between mysql, mysqli and PDO at

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php and
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

The PHP team recommends mysqli or PDO_MySQL for new development:

> It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development. A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. The overall performance of all three extensions is considered to be about the same. Although the performance of the extension contributes only a fraction of the total run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact is as low as 0.1%.

The page also has a feature matrix comparing the extension APIs. The main differences between mysqli and mysql API are as follows:

```
                               mysqli     mysql
Development Status             Active     Maintenance only
Lifecycle                      Active     Long Term Deprecation Announced*
Recommended                    Yes        No
OOP API                        Yes        No
Asynchronous Queries           Yes        No
Server-Side Prep. Statements   Yes        No
Stored Procedures              Yes        No
Multiple Statements            Yes        No
Transactions                   Yes        No
MySQL 5.1+ functionality       Yes        No
```

<sub>* http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799</sub>

There is an additional feature matrix comparing the libraries (new mysqlnd versus libmysql) at

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

and a very thorough blog article at

- http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2012/php-mysql-why-to-upgrade-extmysql/

Answer (score 15):

I have abandoned using mysqli.  It is simply too unstable.  I've had queries that crash PHP using mysqli but work just fine with the mysql package.  Also [mysqli crashes on LONGTEXT columns](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46808).  This bug has been raised in various forms since at least 2005 **and remains broken**.  I'd honestly like to use prepared statements but mysqli just isn't reliable enough (and noone seems to bother fixing it).  If you really want prepared statements go with PDO.

Comment: PDO isn't exactly perfect either (I've run in to some nasty coredumps with it), but at least it has a wider userbase, so it's probably a safer bet.

Comment: @troelskn, so isn't normal mysql just better?

Comment: @Pacerier Considering that it's deprecated, I would say no. In general, it seems that PDO have become the standard choice.

Comment: @troelskn, but deprecated doesn't mean anything except that it wouldn't be there in future versions. In terms of stability, isn't normal mysql more stable?

Comment: At this point (5.5) PHP will actively issue warnings if you use it: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Is this still the state of the art as of 2015?

Comment: Now, in 2017, `mysql` is removed in PHP 7, and `mysqli` is now pretty standard.

Answer (score 13):

MySQLi stands for MySQL improved. It's an object-oriented interface to the MySQL bindings which makes things easier to use. It also offers support for prepared statements (which are **very** useful). If you're on PHP 5 use MySQLi.

Answer (score 5):

What is better is PDO; it's a less crufty interface and also provides the same features as MySQLi.

Using prepared statements is good because it eliminates SQL injection possibilities; using server-side prepared statements is bad because it increases the number of round-trips.

Answer (score 3):

for me, prepared statements is a must-have feature.  more exactly, parameter binding (which only works on prepared statements).  it's the only really sane way to insert strings into SQL commands.  i really don't trust the 'escaping' functions.  the DB connection is a binary protocol, why use an ASCII-limited sub-protocol for parameters?

Comment: PDO usually uses client-side prepared statements, so they aren't really prepared on the server - but this is good, as it saves server resources and usually performs better. The prepared statement "emulation" will always escape things correctly.

Comment: "always" and "escaping" are dangerous words when go together.  i don't know, maybe this code is totally bug-free; but why bother, when a real binary protocol is available? as for performance, that's open to benchmarking.