# MySQL vs MySQLi in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What are the differences/advantages of each? Disadvantages?

I'm not looking for coding preferences or subjective answers.

What are **practical** diferences? (Storage, implementation, how the code looks, environment requirements...)

Comment: Also *[MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/mysqli.prepare) with mysqli.
And there's also a [function to store large (blob) data](http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data) that the "old" mysql extension has not.

```
// php-mysql: no oo-interface
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  die($mysqli->connect_error);
}

// php-mysql: no prepared statements
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (mydata) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);

// php-mysql: no function to send data in chunks
$fp = fopen("php://input", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $chunk = fread($fp, 4096);
  $stmt->send_long_data(0, $chunk);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: +1, Bonus Question - How would I set up MySQLi if I have MySQL installed? Can use MySQLi functions to call MySQL databases?

Comment: You can use both modules to connect to a MySQL server. mysqli is "only" a php module that you can either compile into the php core or load as a module. e.g. *nix distributions often have php-modulename packages you can install through the ditribution's package manager.

Answer (score 9):

Read the [overview](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) on the PHP manual, it answers most questions and has a comparison chart.

Comment: From that overview: "If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead."

Answer (score 3):

Prepared statements are available in mysqli, for one. You can also use the OO interface so instead of `mysql_foo_bar()` you have `$con->foo_bar()`.