# php: grabbing user info from database, is this code secure?

Tags: php

So i was wondering if i this is OK or if theres another better and secure solution to grab info from the database.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
$string = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'");
$v = mysql_fetch_array($string);
}
```

Because I was thinking maybe its possible to hack the "session" and change user_id to another and woops they get access to any user...

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how the `user_id` gets into the Session in the first place.
As a rule of thumb, you should never place any unsanitized values into a query.
You should at least use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). 
Even better would be not to use [the old and outdated mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php) extension but [mysqli's prepared statements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: the user_id gets into the session at the login:
$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  i forgot the escape string, should i do anything to the session lines too?

Comment: @Karem yes. That rule of thumb above really applies to any outside input. Even if you think it might be save: sanitize all user input.

Comment: and by "really applies to any outside input" do you mean that i can apply the mysql_real_escape_string to the $_SESSION['user_id']= $id; too? Or just to all my mysql_query()´s

Comment: @Karem no, just to the query of course. But do have a look at the [native Filter functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest escaping the user_id, just to be sure. You should also test if any rows were found (optional, depends on usage).

Answer (score 0):

Every data coming from the user should be filtered, and never used directly in a query; this would avoid SQL injection.

Suppose the content of `$_SESSION['user_id']` is `' OR id = '12' //`; the query would become `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '' OR id = '12' //'`. Supposing that the user account with ID 12 has particular permissions that allow the user to delete content from the site, you can imagine the consequences.