# Is it bad practice to query a database without providing a link identifier?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In PHP, it is possible to do things like `$results = mysql_query("select ....");`

(see how no link identifier was provided).

The only thing that requires is that a `mysql_connect()` function has been called before, successfully.

Now I tend to alway provide a link identifier but I don't really know why.

Is calling queries without a link identifier any less secure than the other way (providing the link identifier in *every* query)?

Comment: You're just not taking advantage of PHPs default connection handling. But it has no security implications either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link identifier is needed when you have an application that needs to connect to more than one database **server** in the same request/transaction.

It's a good idea to use it even if you only have one database.  "Explicit is better."  Oh wait, that's Python.

Comment: I mean does it reduce the robustness of the system?

Comment: See my updated answer.  You never know, at some point, you may add a second database, and you'll be kicking yourself if you have to refactor a bunch of code.

Comment: to more than one MySQL SERVER! Not database!

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that was unnecessarily ambiguous.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @Nemoden Generally: *if you open more than one connection*.

Comment: is there any reason to use mysql_query over mysqli_query? mysqli_query requires the link identifier

Comment: @yitwail - I won't attempt to reinvent the wheel of thinking on that question, but here's a good SO thread that took this up already:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php

Comment: @AJ, thanks for the link. FYI, the PHP online doc says (regarding mysqli)--If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use this extension--but neglects to say why.

Comment: Yep, keep reading down that page.  It goes on to say quite a bit more about server features that are only supported in mysqli.

Comment: I read all that, AJ. If you need the features that mysql lacks, then mysqli is obviously necessary, but the *strong* recommendation seems to be unconditional. I for one use mysqli by the way, even though mysql would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not any less safe.

However, using `mysql_*()` functions are *less safe* than PDO because they don't have parameter binding by default.

If you switcht to PDO and use `bindParam()`, then it is safer than `mysql_*()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the system will never connect to multiple databases, there are no consequences in practice. I'm sure there are some in theory, which I will be informed of via flaming comments in no time!