# PHP handling of form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hello I am a newbie to PHP, I am using xampp as a local host and html forms to collect data.

my form asks for pacific data, I am trying to get it to put that data into MySQL database client

I am getting error  Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\service_record.php on line 14
 Error:

form code

```
<center>
    <form method="post" action="service_record.php">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="50">
            <center><h1>Record Service Record</h1></center>
            <tr>
                <td>Date joined  <input name="join_date"size="34" maxlength="30"> </td>
                <td>Discharge date  <input name="leave_date"size="34" maxlength="30"><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rank <input name="rank"size="20" maxlength="20"> </td>
                <td>time served <input name="time_served"size="20" maxlength="10"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
               <td>Service <input name="service"size="34" maxlength="30"></td> 
               <td>Regt/Corps  <input name="regt_corps"size="34" maxlength="30"><br /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>

       <input type="reset" value="Reset Form"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input  type="submit" value="Send" />
</center>
    </form>
```

php code

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","client","");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO service_record (join_date,leave_date,rank,time_served,service,regt_corps)
     VALUES
     ('$_POST[join_date]','$_POST[leave_date]','$_POST[rank]','$_POST[time_served]','$_POST[service]','$_POST[regt_corps]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "The Staff Details have been added to database";

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

I have read books after books changed it 100 times still no result.
I have read this site and many others, I just can get it.

Please help if you can.

Rob

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `mysqli_connect`, but then, you are checking for `!mysql_query` and you close it as `mysql_close`.

So, you have to decide if you want to use [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). At first, to try mechanism, use `mysql` everywhere, it should work well. But then, please, rewrite all to `mysqli`, it's newer and better(!).

[When should I use MySQLi instead of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql)

[MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you  Stepo, worked first time, Do I now just change MySQL to mysqli

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, just change the old mysql to new mysqli. If you found my answer useful, you can accept it :))