# how to de-select the database in php

Tags: php, mysql

here is the code ,i select the database for allow the user to create their database with all subject name as a table in created database.i am having problem for creating a new database form inside the another database. in order to do that i have to deselect the first selected database. anybody can help me? thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    $dept=$_SESSION['dept'];

    mysql_select_db("$dept",$con);

// getting all data from create html page

    $year=$_POST["adyear"];

    $table=$_POST["year"];

    $sem=$_POST["sem"];

    $databasename=$_POST["tablename"];

    $table1=$_POST["sub1name"];

    $table2=$_POST["sub2name"];

    $table3=$_POST["sub3name"];

    $table4=$_POST["sub4name"];

    $table5=$_POST["sub5name"];

    $table6=$_POST["sub6name"];

    if($year==""||$table1==""||$table2==""||$table3==""||$table4==""||$table5==""||$table6=="")

{


    echo"<script language=javascript>alert('oops..! you cannot leave subject field empty')</script>";


    echo"<META http-equiv='refresh'; content='0; URL=create.php'>";

}

    else

    {


    $sql="create database $dabasename";
        $s=mysql_query($sql);
        if($s)
        {


        $sql="insert into $table(".$year.",".$sem.",".$databasename.")";
            mysql_close();
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("$databasename",$con);
`       $sql="create table $table1(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal `int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";``

            mysql_query($sql);

            $sql="create table $table2(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";


            mysql_query($sql);

    `       $sql="create table $table3(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal `int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";


            mysql_query($sql);



            $sql="create table $table4(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";


            mysql_query($sql);

            $sql="create table $table5(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";


            mysql_query($sql);

            $sql="create table $table6(REGNO int, NAME varchar(50),Ist_Internal int,II_Internal int,AVG int,ATTENACE int,FINAL_MARK int)";


            mysql_query($sql);

            echo"<script language=javascript>alert('table created now you can enter the student details')</script>";


            echo"<META http-equiv='refresh'; content='0; URL=menu.php'>";
        }


    else


    {


        echo"<script language=javascript>alert('oops...! table name already present. Give different tablename')</script>";




    echo"<META http-equiv='refresh'; content='0; URL=create.php'>";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: mysql_close. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: [Why use MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql) you ask? Well, no you didn't but you should.

Answer (score 0):

to close the first database-:

```
  mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysql_create_db`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php) to create the new database and then switch to it by calling [`mysql_select_db`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Specifically:

```
if(mysql_create_db($dabasename,$con))
{    
    mysql_select_db($dabasename,$con);
    $sql="insert into $table(".$year.",".$sem.",".$databasename.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of the application architecture is wrong.

there should be only **one** database with **one** set of tables, all contains user id to distinguish particular user's data.

**That's the only way.**