# convert mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm completely new to Mysql and PHP. I wrote a script that works but now realise that I should be using mysqli not mysql. I tried changing all the 'mysql_...' to 'mysqli_' but that didn't work. Can anyone tell me exactly how to rewrite the code below?

```
 $tableName = "Fixtures";


  //==== CONNECT TO DATABASE
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);


  //==== FETCH DATA
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");


  //==== PUT DATA INTO ARRAY
  $array = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
  }


  //==== ECHO AS JSON
  echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: You should probably read this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. There's a big list of documentation for individual functions at the bottom of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use MySQLi instead of MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql)

Comment: I was expecting someone to write the code which would show me what needed to be changed. I'm better at reverse engineering code than writing from scratch. I did explain what the problem was AND provided the code. If you read my OP I said the error was that I originally replaced all the 'mysql_' with 'mysqli_' which didn't work. As for the documentation, I've read that, but it's not exactly user friendly (in terms of terminology) for someone new to PHP, mysql and using databases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite simple

```
$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    //etc.
}
```

I find the [php.net documentation on mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) useful for looking up functions as well as codesnippets. This also answers your question [php.net/mysqli_fetch_row](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row)

Comment: Thank you for being the only person to actually provide an answer rather than refer me to documentation I've already checked or just have a go at me for asking the question!