# Twitter oauth getting friednds from std object class and checking with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, oauth

I'm using abarahams oauth and I have been able to retrieve the std class object like so

```
 stdClass Object
 (
    [ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15761916
        [1] => 30144785
        [2] => 382747195
        [3] => 19399719
        [4] => 15962388
        [5] => 119513889
        [6] => 18286505
        [7] => 74829153
        [8] => 20536157
        [9] => 29877699
        [10] => 242314486
        [11] => 17813899
        [12] => 18931678
        [13] => 27791181
        [14] => 13049362
        [15] => 21845792
        [16] => 136361303
        [17] => 50184013
        [18] => 169686021
        [19] => 22733444
        [20] => 30543716
        [21] => 338084918
        [22] => 18182384
        [23] => 16213342
        [24] => 5988062
        [25] => 127640187
        [26] => 181835231
        [27] => 244189163
        [28] => 38919338
        [29] => 66644574
    )

[next_cursor] => 0
[next_cursor_str] => 0
[previous_cursor] => 0
[previous_cursor_str] => 0
 )
all these array value reside in a php variable $following
```

I want to perform a mysql query to check if value and see if there is a match in my database example

```
  mysql_query( " Select id from user where oauth = '$following->ids[$i]'  ");
```

to return my website ids of users. i want all the existing users in my databse who have oauth id to be pulled out and put in an array. i have tried using mysql_fetch assoc but if gived resource id #1,2 etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `var_dump(" Select id from user where oauth = '$following->ids[$i]'  ");` --- and **always** check the string contents before you ask a question. PS: "i have tried using mysql_fetch assoc but if gived resource id #1,2 etc." --- we have no idea how exactly you tried that. You want a particular answer - show a particular code.

Comment: Please use mysqli instead of mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql. or consider using PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/