# How to hide Partial Data in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eperimenting PHP just for fun, But As being newbie, I'm unable to understand curcial parts of PHP....Please help me to sort out this problem which I'm explaining by example :

Suppose

```
$sql = "SELECT id, text,uid FROM feeds WHERE uid='".$ud."' LIMIT 10";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();

if (@mysql_num_rows($items) > 0)
{
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
    {
        $feed = $item[1];
        $nick = getnick($item[2]);
    }
}
```

So I want to display like this :

> 3 Records with **uid** details...
>
> jay,vicky, sumair and **17 others** like this.

Please help me to get output of something like this !!

Thanks !!

Comment: Please use mysqli instead of mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql or consider PDO: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: you can't have 3 records with uid and then say 17 others

Comment: @DevZer0

I want to display something like which facebook like function displaying like :

sunil,zaheer and 7 other like this post.


Isn't it possible to display ???

Comment: @sameer007860, Have you even read my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't stretch this enougth,

## **DO NOT USE MYSQL_*** API anymore. *[<sup>[Read this]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)*

It is **VULNERABLE**, `mysqli_*` functions are just as similar very little difference.

And You already are doing the things required for that output `mysql_num_rows()` already gives the number of total result. So:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($items) > 0)
{
    $count = mysql_num_rows($items);
    echo $count." Records with uid details..."; //Display the count of records

    $threeNameHolder = array; // Hold the first three names on this

    while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items))
    {
        $feed = $item[1];
        $nick = getnick($item[2]);
        if(count($threeNameHolder) < 3) {
            $threeNameHolder[] = $nick;
        } else break; // End the loop here
    }

    //Now display the name
    echo implode(",", $threeNameHolder). " and ".($count - 3)." others like this.";
}
```

#### Safer and MYSQLi Version

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($items) > 0)
{
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($items);
    echo $count." Records with uid details..."; //Display the count of records

    $threeNameHolder = array; // Hold the first three names on this

    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($items))
    {
        $feed = $item[1];
        $nick = getnick($item[2]);
        if(count($threeNameHolder) < 3) {
            $threeNameHolder[] = $nick;
        } else break; // End the loop here
    }

    //Now display the name
    echo implode(",", $threeNameHolder). " and ".($count - 3)." others like this.";
}
```

Comment: Why suppress the `mysqli_num_rows`?

Comment: @DarylGill, Part of OP's code I missed.

Comment: tnq Starx...you gave me what I exactly wanted !!


Thanks allott !!

Answer (score 0):

To understand the basics fundaments, I really recommend the official documentation PHP

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

A simple sample to execute a query and display the output:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT a, b FROM table_name WHERE c='".$something."' LIMIT 10");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

$test = array(); // create a empty array
/* while there is result */
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($items)){
    $columnA = $item[0];// first column (a)
    $columnB = $item[1]); // second column (b)
    $test[] = $columnB; // push_back a item on array
}

echo $num_rows. " Records with **" . $something . "**...";
echo implode($test, ", ") . "and some text";
```