# How to delete and insert simultaneously using a dropdown menu on PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm having troubles trying to insert and delete using a dropdown menu at the same time

```
<div id="blabla">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <p style="position: absolute; top: 185px; left: 58px;">  
            <select name="lista">
                <option selected="selected"></option>
                <optgroup label="Selecciona">
                    <option> Option 1</option>
                    <option> Option 2</option>
                    <option> Option 3</option>
                    <option> Option 4</option>
                    <option> Option 5</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
```

and this is the ADD.php code

```
   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <?php
if(isset($_POST['justifica']) && !empty($_POST['justifica']) &&
isset($_POST['si']) && !empty($_POST['si']) &&
isset($_POST['lista']) && !empty($_POST['lista']))
{
mysql_connect("123", "123", "p123") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("123") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO dos (lista,justifica,si) VALUES ('$_POST[lista]','$_POST[justifica]','$_POST[si]')");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM dos2 WHERE lista5='$_POST[lista]')");
if ($_POST['value'] === '') {
    $_POST['value'] = null; // null en mayuscula si es SQL
}
echo "<img src=imagenes/Satisf.jpg>";
}else{
echo "<img src=imagenes/Error.jpg>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to `INSERT` into table name "dos" and, at the same time, `DELETE` from table name "dos2" when I press the Submit button

On form "Option1" will insert "Option1" on table "dos" and, at the same time, delete "Option1" from table "dos2".

Comment: The answer to this question is just too obvious. It won't help anyone in the future.

Comment: @developerwjk it is? i have no idea what the answer is, guess i'm dumb. user3583216 whats the relationship between dos and dos2, how do we know what id you want to delete?

Comment: Are you trying to INSERT a row into "dos" with "Option 1" as `lista` and DELETE a row in "dos2" that has "Option 1" as `lista`? I know it may sound redundant, but I wanted to clarify your English. If this IS the case, then you do need 2 queries like you have, and the second one will just be: `DELETE FROM dos2 WHERE lista2='$_POST[lista]'`

Comment: @LaughDonor Yeah, thats what i want!, why do u mean i dont need 2 querys?

do i need to combine them or something?

Comment: @user3583216 I did not say you **did not** need 2, I said you **DID** need 2 queries; this is because you are performing 2 different operations to the database, `INSERT` and `DELETE`. Also, you should also consider using [MySQLi over MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql).

Comment: i see, well i didnt work :/, it does not delete row "Option1" on table "dos2"  but it does INSERT into table "dos"

Comment: What columns do you have in "dos" and "dos2"? Also, I saw that you edited your original question and removed your original code which changes the question and **added personal information**.

Comment: woop, yah i update with the new code, i have "lista", "justifica", "si" as a colums on table "dos" and "lista2" as a column on table "dos2"

i want to insert the options on table "dos" column "lista" and delete "the option i pick" on table "dos2" and column "lista2"

Comment: You would likely need to do this in one of three ways: 1) do both query operations in a transactions to make the act atomically 2) create a trigger on the insert table to delete the row from the delete table automatically 3) write a stored procedure to wrap the insert and delete operations.

Comment: @user3583216 Your variables in their $_POST in SQL must have quotes,  `$_POST['lista']`

Comment: @MikeBrant ill try to use one of those methods, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use MySQLi to do this, and I prefer OOP...

```
<?php

class MyDBHandle
{
    public $objDB;

    //Creates the DB Object
    public function Init($strHost, $strUsername, $strPassword, $strDB)
    {
        $this->objDB = new mysqli($strHost, $strUsername, $strPassword, $strDB);

    }

    //SQL Query 1
    public function Dos($strLista, $strJustifica, $strSi)
    {
        $objStatement = $this->objDB->prepare("INSERT INTO dos ('lista', 'justifica', 'si') VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $objStatement->bind_param("sss",
                $strLista, 
                $strJustifica, 
                $strSi);

        $objStatement->execute();
        $objStatement->free_result();
    }

    //SQL Query 2
    public function Dos2($strLista)
    {

        $objStatement = $this->objDB->prepare("DELETE FROM dos2 WHERE lista2=?");
        $objStatement->bind_param("s",
                $strLista);

        $objStatement->execute();
        $objStatement->free_result();
    }

    //disconnect from the db
    public function Disconnect()
    {
        $this->objDB->Close();
    }
}

//db variables
$dbHost = "xxx";
$dbUser = "xxx";
$dbPass = "xxx";
$dbDB = "xxx";

//initialize and connect to the DB
$objDB = new MyDBHandle();
$objDB->Init($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbDB);

//here is a moded version of your code to execute the new methods
if(isset($_POST['justifica']) && !empty($_POST['justifica']) &&
isset($_POST['si']) && !empty($_POST['si']) &&
isset($_POST['lista']) && !empty($_POST['lista']))
{
    $objDB->Dos($_POST['lista'], $_POST['justifica'], $_POST['si']);
    $objDB->Dos2($_POST['lista']);
}
$objDB->Disconnect();


?>
```

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object (line 23, the first bind)<- , im undersating ur code and i know by now that bind_param is substitute for those (?) but i didnt find a way to make it work

Comment: If you look, all of the DB code is written within the "class MyDBHandle { ... }". You must have that written above your initialization of the object with "$objDB = new MyDBHandle()". Just like you have to write a function above the area you use it.

Comment: yes is written like that (same as the code u posted, the only thing i changed was the db variables).. you mean i have to add some more code or something?

Comment: I had some bad code (some of my template code) within Dos2. Recopy Dos2. Sorry.

Comment: Still give me an error, Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 24, i cant figure it out what the problem is :/

Comment: The SQL Statement is failing ($this->objDB->prepare). You will need to run it by hand and see why it's failing, or you can do some try, catch.

Comment: I had a typo. The table is called "lista2", not "lista5".