# mysqli extension error in php script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not good in PHP, I have problem to process with my sign form to using the php script, the server had returned me a message below:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/tz005/public_html/test2/email-activation-script.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/tz005/public_html/test2/email-activation-script.php on line 19
Failed to sent email activation code
```

Can anyone check what is the problem on my script.Here is my script:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$db_host = "server";
$db_name = "table";
$db_use = "user";
$db_pass = "pass";
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($db_name, $link);
$chars = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
$length = 5;
$textstr = "";
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
   $textstr .= $chars[rand(0, count($chars)-1)];
}
$query = "INSERT INTO email_activation (username, password, email, postcode, activation) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$postcode','$textstr')";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if ($result) {
echo "Sign up successfully,please check your email for activation code.<br>";
$mail_to="$email";
$mail_subject="Email Activation";
$mail_body = "This is the email to activate your account.\n";
$mail_body.="Your activation code is: $textstr \n";
$mail_body.="Click the following link to activate your account.\n";
$mail_body.="<a href='activation-form.php?username=$username&activation=$textstr'>Click here</a>";
$sent = mail($mail_to,$mail_subject,$mail_body, "From: freecycle@greenwich.co.uk");
echo "$mail_to<br><b>$mail_subject</b><br><br>$mail_body";
}else{
echo "Failed to sent email activation code";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
mysqli_select_db($db_name, $link);
```

to

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name);
```

also change

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass db name in connection string so need to select db with function try

```
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass, $db_name);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

For more :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments the wrong way around for the `mysqli_select_db()` call. The first argument should be the link, the second being the string database name. So change to:

```
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name);
```

Secondly, In the query call, you need to pass the link, not just the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

References:

- [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)
- [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli doesn't work the way the Mysql functions work, You need to define the connection in a variable to make use of the function.

However you could just change your functions to mysql (if installed) and it'll work.

Basicly:

```
mysqli_select_db
```

Becomes

```
mysql_select_db
```

Etcetera, this will probably be fine for your project.
If you get more at ease with PHP look at the classes to handle your Database, I guess you'll find those yourself.

Comment: This isn't good advice, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php

Comment: True I guess. He is using the mysqli functions as mysql functions though.