# Drop Down List and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I have a drop down list with Select Option and information written inside are retrieved from the database with a query .

```
<select name="moto">
      <?php 
        include 'connessione.php';
        $qry = "SELECT NomeOggetto FROM Oggetto";
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<option value='.$row["NomeOggetto"].'>'.$row["NomeOggetto"].'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

The problem is that if in the menu i have the name of a motorbike with one space between its name , for example ( Kawasaki Ninja) , when i send it to the PHP page with the POST Method it only displays Kawasaki . How can i show the entire name with the space included ? this is the php page :

```
<?php  echo $_POST['moto'];  ?>
```

Comment: [Don't use `mysql_*` in an application; use `mysqli_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql).

Comment: Doesn't work if i use mysqli . Values won't even show in the drop down list.

Comment: `mysqli_*` will work *better* than `mysql_*` does. There was probably just a bug in your code - you would have been better off asking about that bug, plus this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put quotes around your attribute values in your HTML

from

```
echo '<option value='.$row["NomeOggetto"].'>'.$row["NomeOggetto"].'</option>';
```

to

```
echo '<option value="'.$row["NomeOggetto"].'">'.$row["NomeOggetto"].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and decode it.

You can also print it as `echo " '$_POST['moto']' "` will print `word1 word2` as 1 string because it is wrapped in quotes:

Try to `print_r($_POST);` and see if you're posting the entire string.

Comment: An HTML `select` will automatically urlencode the data.