# Error! Call to undefined function pg_insert()

Tags: php, arrays, database

I am trying to copy an array into a table in the test database. I get this fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_insert() in C:\wamp\www\Lessons\GMS-DB.php on line 31. Can u please help me!
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$database = "test";


//                       Create server connection 
$con = mysql_connect ($servername, $username, $password, $database) or       die('cant connect server');

mysql_select_db('test',$con);

//                      Create database connection

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test',$con);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   //                               Specify directory

$dir    = 'C:/Users/Desktop/data';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$data = array_diff($files1, array('.', '..')); //remove the dots or periods
// print_r($data);
//                               put in a string
$matstring = implode("','",$data);
$matstring="".$matstring."";
$table_name = `test table 1`;

$res = pg_insert ($con ,  $table_name , $data);
if ($res) {
      echo "POST data is successfully logged\n";
  } else {
      echo "User must have sent wrong inputs\n";
  }


?>
```

Comment: Where is your `pg_connect()` if you already use `pg_insert()` ?

Comment: he's using mysql datase and using pg_insert to insert data

Comment: `mysql_connect` and `pg_insert` dont go together. But that error message actually means you dont have PostGreSQL extension installed/enabled. Since most of your code is mysql based, probably you wanted mysql_query there?`

Comment: Sidenote: `$con = mysql_connect ($servername, $username, $password, $database)` that is [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) syntax using 4 parameters. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php the syntax is "server, username, password", then pass the DB to `mysql_select_db` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different kinds of databases there. One is `MySQL` and another is `PostgreSQL`. Your using a mysql database so use a mysql query to insert.

You need to use `mysql` query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (column_name, column_name2) VALUES('$value', '$value2')");
```

Also, you are using `mysqli` syntax to connect to db. In `mysql`, the syntax is

```
$con = mysql_connect ($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db('foo', $con);
```

And I strongly suggest you to use mysqli. Ancient mysql is no longer supported!

Here's the code in `MySQLi`

```
$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
$db->query("INSERT INTO $table (column_name, column_name2) VALUES('$value', '$value2')");
```

[When should I use MySQLi instead of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql)

[MySQLi Query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Comment: come on thats a typo..-.-

Comment: Nonetheless, rendering the code invalid and fail. Syntax is syntax; I didn't come up with it, I only follow it ;-)

Comment: You also missed something in OP's code. [Click here to read my comment about it...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613250/error-call-to-undefined-function-pg-insert/28613342#comment45530456_28613250).

Comment: Ya..I think thats about it