# MySql php get and insert syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a syntax error after I added another value to be added to the data base. I have no idea what is the problem I'm kinda new to php and mysql.
what am i doing wrong?

> ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''index',name,score) VALUES ('2','guyaa','300')' at line 1

this is the insert php:

```
<?php
require_once 'app_config.php';
connect();

$index = $_GET['index'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$score = $_GET['score'];

$query = "INSERT INTO scores (index,name,score) VALUES ('" . $index ."','" . $name ."','" . $score . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('ERROR: '. mysql_error());
```

and this is the retrieve :

```
<?php
require_once 'app_config.php';
connect();

$query = "SELECT * From scores";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $item['index'];
echo ' - ';
echo $item['name'];
echo ' - ';
echo $item['score'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: looks fine, so print your query here.. with real values and error code..

Comment: Also note that mysql_ is deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql

Comment: `index` is a MySQL reserved word - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html - so it needs to be wrapped with backticks - `\`index\`` -> `$query = "INSERT INTO scores (\`index\`,name,score) VALUES ...`

Comment: i change to this :
$query = "INSERT INTO scores ('index',name,score) VALUES ('" . $index ."','" . $name ."','" . $score . "')";

and added brackets and i still got the error :(

Comment: (1) you used single quotes `'` **not** backticks `\``. quotes are used for string values, backticks are used for identifiers. (2) It is common courtesy on SO that if you have an error message that you include it in your question. Without the error message you are assuming we are mind readers, and basically wasting everyone's time.

Comment: thanks guys i was need to add brackets so i added ' but thats not good i needed to add ` instead when i used index.... thanks :)

Comment: Always use backticks for field names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index is a MySQL [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You need to use backticks

```
$query = "INSERT INTO scores (`index`,name,score) VALUES ('" . $index
."','" . $name ."','" . $score . "')";
```