# Message not getting printed on the browser in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code in php:

```
    <?php echo "hello world";
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root123");
    echo "Connected";
    mysql_close($con);
    echo  "hell"; ?>
```

Its printing hello world ,connected ,hell in terminal but it only prints hello world when  i run it in the browser. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: This wont answer your question, but you should still give this a look. You should not use the deprecated mysql-extension, instead use the newer mysqli-extension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql

Comment: Then why it is working in terminal properly?

Comment: you dont catch errors. put this after `mysql_connect`: `if($con === false) { echo mysql_error();}` [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: this code is run perfectly.. are you sure you run this file

Comment: I think your PHP might have no MySQL drivers installed. Check loaded extensions/modules of PHP with phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` instead.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "collectively-codeigniter";
echo "hello world";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Not Connected";
} else {
    echo "Connected";
}
// Close connection
$conn->close();

echo "hell";
?>
```

Comment: Will the above code run in browser like localhost/file_name.php??

Comment: Mine it still doesn't.

Comment: remove everything and , add `<php echo "aaa"; ?>`. See what is coming in browser.

Comment: its printing everything  in browser before the the connect statement in php file.

Comment: at the beginning of the file, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

May be there has occurred an error in server side and server is not showing informatin about error. You look at `error.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see syntax errors and since you said that `echo()` functions before the connection line work, I guess the problem could be the connection:

1. Replace `mysql_connect` with `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_close` with `mysqli_close` because `mysql_*` is now **deprecated**.
2. Add the following code after the connection line:

   ```
   if (!$con) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }
   ```

This will check if the connection succeeded and if it failed it will print the error description.

Other things that could cause the problem are:

- You do not have `MySQL` modules installed
- `MySQL` service is not running (to check windows services: run -> services.msc)

Let me know if this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously running into an error server side before the output has a chance to take place. Possibly it's when you try and connect to the mysql server that everything goes south. That results in an error that you have configured PHP not to show (very good for production, not so good when developing), thus you see "nothing".

Start by enabling error reporting in PHP via the php config file or setting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your script. That should give you a clearer picture of what you issue actually is. A guess would be that you are unable to connect to the mysql server due to privileges on the mysql server, the port used, credentials or something of that nature.

Also, as stated, depending on the version of PHP you are running `mysql_*` command are deprecated and you should instead use the `mysqli_*` functions, `PDO` or something like that.