# php json_encode mysql result in specific way

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am json encoding result from a mysql query in a php file. My php script is as follows:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

**My Output**

```
[
  {
    "0": "Variables",
    "topic_name": "Variables",
    "1": "pyt1.1",
    "rdf_id": "pyt1.1",
    "2": "Hello World",
    "ex_name": "Hello World",
    "3": "1",
    "line_number": "1",
    "4": "print (\"Hello World!\")",
    "code": "print (\"Hello World!\")",
    "5": "Some Comment",
    "comment": "Some Comment"
  }
]
```

Here, as you can see every alternate lines are redundant. I do not need lines 1,3,5...and so on.

**Desired Output**

```
[
  {
    "topic_name": "Variables",
    "rdf_id": "pyt1.1",
    "ex_name": "Hello World",
    "line_number": "1",
    "code": "print (\"Hello World!\")",
    "comment": "Some Comment"
  }
]
```

How to change the php script to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) has 2 parameters. The second parameter is the result type and is set by default to `MYSQL_BOTH` which means it returns both numerical and column names as keys. Use it like:

```
mysql_fetch_array($stmt, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

**NOTE**: `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should consider starting to use `mysqli_` functions, `MySQLi` class or `PDO`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped! Hope I could accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should use [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) with a *MYSQL_ASSOC* flag:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) )
```

Important from the docs:

> Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0.

Like referred in the docs you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891552/5297359

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped!