# How to insert an array into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I've got the following array:

```
$dati = array(
    "data" => array(
        'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
        'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
        'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
        'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
        'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
    )
);
```

and I want to insert `$dati["data"]['location'] in database.`
How can I fix

```
mysql_query("INSERT into utenti(city) VALUES ('$dati[data][location]')") or die (mysql_error());
```

?

Comment: Change `$dati[data][location]` to `$dati['data']['location']` ?

Comment: What happens currently?

Comment: To begin, use [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql)

Comment: It says: error @Maximus2012

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*At first*, use proper variable interpolation:

```
mysql_query("INSERT into utenti(city) VALUES ('{$dati["data"]["location"]}')") or die (mysql_error());
```

*Secondly*, `mysql_` extension is deprecated, use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: any comments about SQL Injection or deprecated mysql_* extensions ?

Comment: @devlincarnate, see my comments

Comment: using `{}` to enclose arrays requires the use of quotes on the array keys, otherwise you'll get the undefined constant warning.

Comment: @MarcB, sure, I've missed that thing writing it at late night. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

PHP's parser is not greedy, and multi-dimensional arrays in double-quoted strings will NOT parse properly. e.g.

```
$arr['a']['b'] = 'c';
echo "$arr[a][b]";
```

will print `Array[b]`, not `c` as you expect, because PHP stops parsing for arrays after the first `[]` key.

You have to use the `{}` extended notation:

```
echo "{$arr['a']['b']}"; // prints c as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Use somthing like below

```
mysql_query("INSERT into utenti(city) VALUES ('".$dati['data']['location']."')") or die (mysql_error());
```

> **Note:** mysql_ extension is deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead.