# php - db insert error - query was empty

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to insert some records into the db and i'm getting this error: `Query was empty`

```
$data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$usercomment= mysql_real_escape_string($data->usercomment);
$wardrobe= mysql_real_escape_string($data->wardrobe);
$ctype= mysql_real_escape_string($data->ctype);
$pic= mysql_real_escape_string($data->pic);
$vtype= mysql_real_escape_string($data->vtype);

$query=mysql_query ("INSERT INTO db.comment(`comment`,`pic`,`wardrobe`,`comment_type`,`vtype`)
VALUES('".$usercomment."','".$pic."','".$wardrobe."','".$ctype."','".$vtype."')");
$Result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're adding a mysql_query inside a mysql_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query` is already a `mysql_query`, so you can't add it inside the other `mysql_query`.

You can make `$query` be the `string` for the `mysql_query` below it.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO db.comment(`comment`,`pic`,`wardrobe`,`comment_type`,`vtype`)    VALUES('".$usercomment."','".$pic."','".$wardrobe."','".$ctype."','".$vtype."')";

$result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions, use `mysqli_*` instead.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891552/4802649) for more details on why.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code.. try this

```
data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$usercomment= mysql_real_escape_string($data->usercomment);
$wardrobe= mysql_real_escape_string($data->wardrobe);
$ctype= mysql_real_escape_string($data->ctype);
$pic= mysql_real_escape_string($data->pic);
$vtype= mysql_real_escape_string($data->vtype);

$query="INSERT INTO db.comment(`comment`,`pic`,`wardrobe`,`comment_type`,`vtype`)
VALUES('".$usercomment."','".$pic."','".$wardrobe."','".$ctype."','".$vtype."')";
$Result1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```