# Use of Foreach loop to assign array values to multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am currently in the process of making a quiz, with the table format:

```
| id |     question     | option1 | option2 | option3 | answer |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | What is my name? |  Dave   |   Bob   | Charles | Linda  |
```

I am trying to verify user's answers and I'm not quite sure how to go about it.  I am a bit stumped using the foreach loop to assign array values to other arrays.  The following code within matresult.php incorrect but it should show what I am trying to achieve:

Within matquiz.php I have

```
//MySql query to select all data from matquiz table
$query="SELECT * FROM MatQuiz";                        
//Assign the query to a result variable
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
CODE
}
```

Within matresult.php I have

```
$array3 = array();
$array4 = array();
$array5 = array();
$array6 = array();
$array7 = array();
$array8 = array();

$finalresults = array($row['ID'], $row['question'], $row['option1'], $row['option2'], $row['option3'], $row['answer']);

foreach($finalresults as $value){                                

     array_push($array3, $value['ID']);      //ID
     array_push($array4, $value['question']);  //question
     array_push($array5, $value['option1']); //op1
     array_push($array6, $value['option2']); //op2
     array_push($array7, $value['option3']); //op3
     array_push($array8, $value['answer']);  //answer
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to push each $finalresults array value into 6 seperate arrays, and do this for 5 questions/rows.

So for example, I want array3 to hold all 5 question IDs. [1,2,3,4,5] and I would like array4 to hold all 5 questions etc.

I am aware that the syntax within the foreach loop is wrong but this is my question to you, how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: From looking at what you have done, it looks correct, albeit a bit verbose. What issues/errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` just once? If the query is expected to return several rows, you will need to call it in a `while` loop. Be advised also that the `mysql_*()` functions were deprecated long ago and no longer available by default in recent PHP versions. mysqli or PDO are suitable replacements.

Comment: It is called within a while loop, as per the **EDIT**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should probably be using mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_array, as those are more common nowadays. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891552/5347875) for reasons why.

I also think you don't need the foreach at all, just use mysqli_fetch_array in a while loop, no need for another loop in there.

As for the array_push() calls, you could write those like this:

```
$array3[] = $row['ID'];
```

And they have the same effect, and I think that is more common. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) in the PHP manual. When you don't put an specific index in an array assignment, PHP just assigns to the next available numeric index.

I'm not sure what you are using $finalresults for, but it isn't needed either as far as I can tell, since you were just using it as a temporary holding area for data you were going to assign to your array3-array8 anyway. I've removed that from my example.

This example has everything in the same file, split it up if you need to:

```
<?php

$array3 = array();
$array4 = array();
$array5 = array();
$array6 = array();
$array7 = array();
$array8 = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM MatQuiz";                        
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $array3[] = $row['ID'];
  $array4[] = $row['question'];
  $array5[] = $row['option1'];
  $array6[] = $row['option2'];
  $array7[] = $row['option3'];
  $array8[] = $row['answer'];

}
```

Comment: Ideal! Thank you very much, seems I was vastly over complicating things.  Still very new to using php. I will update the code to use mysqli also.  Appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!