# While fetch row in PHP

Tags: php

I have that

```
<?php
   $new=get_records("tbl_item","status=1 AND idshop='{$idshop}' AND special","id DESC", $startRow.",".$pageSize, " ");
   $dem=1;
   while($row_new=mysql_fetch_assoc($new)){
?>  
<div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want when this code run, it'll display 1 row with 4 col-3 until the end of the loop.

I want output like this

```
<div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div>
<div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Please help me! Thanks all!

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: i want when this loop run, it have display <div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div> @hungrykoala

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. You should switch to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
    $new=get_records("tbl_item","status=1 AND idshop='{$idshop}' AND special","id DESC", $startRow.",".$pageSize, " ");
    $i=0;
    while($row_new=mysql_fetch_assoc($new)){
        if($i % 4 == 0) {
?>  
<div class="row">
<?php
        }
?>  
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
<?php
        if($i % 4 == 3) {
?>  
</div>
<?php
        }
?>  
<?php 
        $i++;
    }
    $i--;
    if ($i % 4 != 3) {
?>  
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

The last `if` is in case the total number of records weren't a multiple of 4, then we need to close the `div` tag.

And, not to mention, you should definitely use MySQLi. [Why should I use MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891552/1393400)

Comment: Updated again... The code is fairly simple and clean to read. Hope it helped.

Comment: still not working bro, here full code https://github.com/namntx/MinCSS/blob/master/stack.php

Comment: Ah missed a php tag just before the `if($i % 4 == 3)`. Corrected it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Please ^ upvote my answer if you liked it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: Email me. I'll write to you there.

Answer (score 0):

try this bro:

update, if count rows less then 4:

```
$new = get_records("tbl_item", "status=1 AND idshop='{$idshop}' AND special", "id DESC", $startRow . "," . $pageSize, " ");
$dem = 1;
$x = 0;
$count = count($new);
while ($row_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($new)) {
    $x++;
    if ($x==1 || $x % 4 == 1) { ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="col-3">
        <?= "x: $x" ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($x % 4 == 0 || $x == $count) { ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the result? and you expect? anyway, you should move to mysqli, mysql is already depreceated

Comment: <div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div>
<div class=""row>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
   <div class="col-3">
   </div>
</div>

Comment: I want result like this.

Comment: have you tried my codes? can you show us the result of my codes?

Comment: please check again

Comment: sorry bro, i forgot about the first row. please check my codes again

Comment: make sure you implement this:  if ($x==1 || $x % 4 == 1) {

Comment: can you teamviewer?

Comment: sure. just let me know if you still need it. sorry was outside before

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php

   $new=get_records("tbl_item","status=1 AND idshop='{$idshop}' AND special","id DESC", $startRow.",".$pageSize, " ");
   $dem=1;

   while($row_new=mysql_fetch_assoc($new)){

?>  
<div class="row">

    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++){?>
       <div class="col-3">
       </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: product have been duplicate 4