# Using php to print data from database which has one of item in its column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will try to better explain what I am looking for.

I want to check all rows from mysql database that has one of item in its column.

Lets say that I have database with 3 columns :`id,name,tags`

[image: This is how my database looks]

and variable `$interests = "nature,sky,tehnology"`

I want to search all rows of my database and return true if there is at least one match of word of $interests inside column tags

Example:

If variable is: `$interests = "nature,sky,tehnology,math;"`
and column tags has value of `nature,sky,tehnology`  How can I use SQL  to check if there are things that are in both variable $interests and in column tags

So result from example would be true because there are 3 things that are in both variable and column: nature,sky,tehnology

Comment: Please tag the question with the DB used, is it MySQL ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your column tag contains `"love,science,nature"` in 1 cell ? or every row contains 1 word ?

Comment: A database has no columns. I suppose you mean table.

Comment: Can you please see eddited question, I inserted link of my database

Answer (score -1):

You can check if there's a match like this: (OOP)

```
$sql = $dbconnection->query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE interests = $interests');
if($sql->num_rows > 0) {
// do whatever you want to do when there is a match
} else {
echo 'No match has been found!';
exit();
}
```

Procedural style:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnection, 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE interests  = '.$interests);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
// do whatever you want to do when there is a match
} else {
echo 'No match has been found!';
}
```

I don't know if you're familiar with prepared statements, but I do recommend you using them.
OOP & Prepared statements:

```
$sql = $dbconnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE interests = ?');
$sql->bind_param('s', $interests);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
if($sql->num_rows > 0) {
// do whatever you want to do when there is a match
} else {
echo 'No match has been found!';
exit();
}
```

I also recommend you using MySqli instead of MySql, since MySql is deprecated for PHP7 and MySqli does support Prepared Statements and MySql does not. ([When should I use MySQLi instead of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql))
I hope this helped you.

**Edit**
You need to fetch all rows.

```
$sql = $dbconnection->query('SELECT * FROM table_name);
$result = $sql->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->free_result();
```

And then you search in the `$row` variable for a match. 
I recommend you using an array for `$interests`, because it's easier to search in the indexes. (You can use array_search / in_array)

Comment: Can you please look at question again? I eddited it. Problem is that I need to check if at lease 1 word from tag interests matches the value from tags