# PHP / MYSQL - Can't get ID for each entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am at scripting a customer database. When I wanted to implement the "manage customers" site where you can edit, delete and view details of each entry, I encountered a strange problem. Everything works like expected, but the ID field is left empty and added nowhere.

I have the following code:

```
    <?php
$qresult = mysql_query("SELECT ID , FirstName, LastName, Company FROM hs_customers");

echo "<table class='coverview' border='0' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Options</th>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qresult))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>" . 
     "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>" . 
     "<td>" . $row['Company'] . "</td>" . 
     "<td>" . "<a href='?action=details&id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>Details</a>" .     " " . 
     "<a href='?action=edit&id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>Edit</a>" . " " . 
     "<a href='?action=delete&id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>Delete</a>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Do people learn to read or not? Mysql_* function so bad....

Comment: as far as I can see, you are selecting an ID field, and using uid on the rows

Comment: wow, check all the reactions... the problem is obvius

Comment: Why do people say its, "so bad."  It's still in use today on older systems and is still functional.  I have a project I built years ago that uses mysql functions and performs very well to this day.  As shown on this post, the main advantage of mysqli vs mysql is that it uses prepared statements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php.  If you're not using those, then you shouldn't encounter any issues...

Answer (score 5):

You use `$row['uid']` but you select `ID` from your query, so should be `row['ID']`

Moreover, don't use anymore function like `mysql_query`. As you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is discouraged. Please use [msqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead.

The best solution is to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). Please take a look to them too.

Comment: It's even better if he uses `PDO` instead of `mysqli`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
@DonCallisto - i was using ID too i forgot to edit it back while posting it here - still same result. 

I didn't knew that this is obsolete. Thank you for the tip ;)

Answer (score 2):

shouldnt it be:

```
$row['ID']
```

instead of

```
$row['uid']
```

Answer (score 1):

You echo

```
$row['uid']
```

But your Selecting from de database:

```
$row['ID']
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess it's just because you use `$row['uid']` but in your SQL query you're using `ID`. You should be using `$row['ID']` instead.