# MYSQL: Insert column if not exists

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a column by checking if it exists. If not it should give message that it already exists with the code below.

```
$prefix = 'vm_';
$col_name = 'checking';

$col = "SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$prefix."users";

if (!$col){
    $insert_col = "ALTER TABLE ".$table." ADD ".$col_name." DATETIME NOT NULL";

    mysql_query($insert_col);

    echo $col_name.' has been added to the database';
} else {
    echo $col_name.' is already exists';
}
```

But it doesn't add any column and directly displays message that the column already exists.

Comment: You have to run the query first. And please use mysqli as mysql is in the deprecation process @pixelngrain

Comment: where to use mysqli? for $col=mysqli or everywhere? I am new to mysql and don't know if anything wrong

Comment: Please check the answer provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the final code. There was stupid mistake; I didn't use `mysql_query` for `$col`

```
$prefix = 'vm_';
$col_name = 'checking';

$col = mysql_query("SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$prefix."users");


if (!$col){
    //$insert_col = "ALTER TABLE ".$table." ADD ".$col_name." DATETIME NOT NULL";

    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE ".$prefix."users ADD ".$col_name." DATETIME NOT NULL");

    echo $col_name.' has been added to the database';
} else {
    echo $col_name.' is already exists';
}
```

Comment: please note this doesn't work. It'll will throw a fatal error and render the rest of the script useless.

Answer (score 8):

You never execute your query, your condition is instead your query string:

```
if (!$col) { //always false, since a nonempty string is always truthy
```

Comment: Ah give me a sec let me try one thing. In fact I just realized my stupid mistake I didn't user mysql_query for $col.

Comment: Its done. that was really stupid mistake.. I will ask to remove this question.. thanks.. or may be I can keep with my solution

Answer (score 3):

You have to run your query before you check statements with it. It's like you can't see whether the box is empty of not (i.e. result of your query) without opening the box (i.e. running the query)

Replace your line 04 with this

```
$col = mysql_query("SELECT ".$col_name." FROM ".$prefix."users");
```

Then your problem will be solved

> For more information on mysqli, please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891836/1609555)

You might consider moving on to PDO statements as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that's true. Thanks a lot. However I realized after sometime of posting my stupid question and corrected can see in my own answer. Please know if anything wrong in that.. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You haven't executed your query. First execute your query, then check the condition on it.

Comment: Try not to use any mysql_* function. Start using mysqli

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it works:

```
$db= new mysqli('host','user','password','db');
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename LIKE 'columnname'";
$db->query($query);
if(empty(empty($db->num_rows)) { 
   $alter = "ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname varchar(50) NOT NULL"; 
   $db->query($alter); 
} else { 
   echo 'column exists';
}
```