# dropdown from two tables, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Say I have the two following tables:

country_table:

```
---------------------------------
|ID|country_code|country_name   |
|01|CA          |Canada         |
|02|US          |United States  |
---------------------------------
```

user_table:

```
----------------------------------------------
|id|user_id|country_code|email_address       |
|01|oswalsh|CA          |blah@hotmail.com    |
|02|jlong  |US          |blah2@hotmail.com   |
----------------------------------------------
```

I am creating my user signup/edit account forms, and have a drop down for country. Originally I had simply stored the country_name in the user_table instead of using a country_code, however I have also decided to implement a map script...which is a massive mess of javascript files which make use of the country_code.

Thus I created the country_table so I could match the country_code and the country_name so I could map user interactions...However I am not sure how to go about creating the sql statement for the drop down.

What I have so far:

```
<?php
    include ('../../connect.php');

    $account_panel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id=1")
            or die(mysql_error());

            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $account_panel )) 
    {
?>
<select name="event_country" id="event_country"  required />
        <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $row1['user_country']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['user_country']; ?></option>

        <?php           
            $countries = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country_table")
            or die(mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $countries )) 
            {
                echo "<option value='". $row['value'] ."'>". $row['name'] ."</option>";
            }   
                echo "</select>";
        ?>

        <?php
        }
        mysql_close($connection);
        ?>
```

So as you should be able to see from above what is happening, is that the list is populated from the country_table, but I am trying to get the selected value from the user table. This does seem to work, but my problem is that the country code is what is stored and being displayed. So say I am grabbing the info for oswalsh...me...the country returned is CA, and I would like it to display Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need to familiarize yourself with [SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

To join those two tables and get the `country_name` along with the user data from the `user_table`, you'd need an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT ut.*, ct.country_name
FROM user_table ut
INNER JOIN country_table ct
ON ut.country_code = ct.country_code
```

In your case, this would result in the following:

```
1   oswalsh CA  blah@hotmail.com    Canada
2   jlong   US  blah2@hotmail.com   United States
```

Also, you should consider using `mysqli_` and stop using `mysql_` functions. Here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php) on this topic on SA.