# Difference between mysql & mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql vs mysqli in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

What is the difference between  `mysql_* functions` and  `mysqli_* functions`? Is there any technical reasons behind we shouldn't use `mysql_* functions`?

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are on the  way of depreciation

Comment: `mysql_*` are already deprecated in newer PHP versions

Answer (score 10):

The "i" stands for "improved". The list of improvements can be found in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php).

MySQLi is the OOP version of MySQL extension. In the end, MySQLi and MySQL accomplish the same thing: they are extension for interacting with MySQL from PHP. A lot of people still use the original MySQL extension instead of the new MySQLi extension because MySQLi requires MySQL 4.1.13+ and PHP 5.0.7+ .

MySQLi supports some things that the old MySQL extension doesn't. Things like prepared statements, multiple statements, and transactions on top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php should explain all the differences