# delete data from phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include_once("FTMdatabase.php");
$id = $_GET['AccountID'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM personaldetails WHERE AccountID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$msg = "Data Has Been Removed";
confirm($msg);
mysql_close();
?>
<?php
function confirm($msg)
{
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
alert(\"".$msg."\");
document.location.href='FTMlogin.php';
</script>";
}
?>
```

I try this code. But I got an error that says 'AccountID' undefined index. My 1st row in the database is AccountID. Why does it happen?

```
<?php
include_once("FTMdatabase.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM personaldetails";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['AccountID'];
$name = $row['Name'];
$phone = $row['Phone'];
$car = $row['Car'];
$comment = $row['Comment'];
?>
<table border="1">
<tr><td width="10"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td width="10"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
<td width="300"><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
<td width="100"><?php echo $car; ?></td>
<td width="100"><?php echo $comment; ?></td>
</tr>
<td><a href="FTMdelete.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">
Delete</a>
</table>
<?php
```

This is where to get `$id`. The reason I use `$_GET['AccountID']`

Comment: $_GET['AccountID'];  is used when you are sending data from url like  localhost/abc.php?AccountID=1

Comment: Please see: [http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: try to echo $id and check that there is any value in $id or not?

Comment: tried it.same error came out.i think there is no value in $id since it doenst show anything

Comment: Did you know hows you are sending this value `AccountID`. is it through GET(query string in url) or POST(form or something with method post)

Comment: it should get the value from the database?

Comment: when you are getting the value from db then why you are using$_GET. And i don't see any code that you write to  get that `AccountId` from db.

Comment: oh wait.i cannot get it from the database since i am using $id to delete the data on the database.so basically i should get the value from other form?

Comment: and what's the method that form haveing there? get or post?

Comment: sorry to ask but whats the different between get and post?

Comment: Handling and how's they pass to somewhere is main difference. get goes mostly as url parameter which we call `query string` and handled with $_GET. post goes as http body which is handled by $_POST. both can handle by $_REQUEST(common), but it's not in use.

Comment: be careful about sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are facing is not database error it's an php warning.

'AccountID' undefine index is because of this line

```
$_GET['AccountID'];
```

this is because you do not pass the AccountID to the page.
You should use like this

```
if($isset($_GET['AccountID'])){
   echo "No value for AccountID given";
exit;
}
```

If you are using mysql_query(); then there is no need of connection so

the line

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

Should be like this

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

By the way mysql is deprecated so use mysqli.

So the final result code will look like this

```
<?php
include_once("FTMdatabase.php");
if($isset($_GET['AccountID'])){
   echo "No value for AccountID given";
   exit;
}
$id = $_GET['AccountID'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM personaldetails WHERE AccountID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
  $msg = "Data Has Been Removed";
  confirm($msg);
} else {
  echo "error on query";
}

mysql_close();

function confirm($msg)
{
 echo "<script language=\"javascript\">
 alert(\"".$msg."\");
 document.location.href='FTMlogin.php';
 </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: deprecated? soryy i'm a newbie so i didnt know much about mysql.what is the difference between mysql and mysqli?

Comment: check this link this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151458/difference-between-mysql-mysqli