# Count the amount of values in a Mysql table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a school voting with 10 questions. There you can check one teacher for every question (in total there are 80 teachers). When someone has voted for all questions, a new row in my mysql table will be inserted.

My Mysql Table has 10 fields (for every question one(q1,q2,q3)). The name of the teacher for one question will be an integer (every teachers has an id from 1 - 82).

[That is what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMhaT.png)

Now I want to find out for which teacher is how often voted for each question. That should do a php script. It should echo something like this:

[The result should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78a53.png)

How to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at group by and sum
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give number of times each teacher is voted for question q1.

```
$sql = "SELECT q1, COUNT(*) AS votes FROM table1 GROUP BY q1 ORDER BY votes";
$ref = $result->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ref))
{
  echo "$row[votes] times $row[q1]</br>";

}
```

You can do the same for other questions,  just by changing the column name for question number

Comment: it does not alert somethign :/ ?

Comment: You can process it using php

Comment: when i do your above code in an echo and do the query it givess me Resource id #4 ?

Comment: i got his when i use your code: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /users/marien-ranking/www/auswertung.php on line 12

Comment: what is $result

Comment: $result = mysqli_connect("localhost","usernmae","password","dbname");

Comment: Change result to your connetion variable

Comment: $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");

$db = mysql_select_db("xxx");

Comment: Replace $result with $verbindung. Also use mysqli_ functions instead of mysql_ functions()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151458/difference-between-mysql-mysqli

Comment: you dont need anything extra to use mysqli_functions. Just change mysql_ functions to mysqli_functions

Comment: oh sry another one, how to sort the output?

Comment: based on what ?

Comment: You can use order by votes in the sql query. Check the edited code. Now the rows will be in sorted order