# parse error, sql Database and php

Tags: php, sql

i am getting this error after uploading my page to server :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in
>   /data/19/1/86/59/1901711/user/xxxx/htdocs/Maxxxxxxt/Mxxxxxxe/Pxx/txxx/index.php
>   on line 11

on line i have this database statement , which is working fine when i am using it at localhost.

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); or  die(mysql_error());
```

i have tried up every settings but they are all helpless, let me know what i am doing wrong ? and what is to be done to fix it up ?

Comment: You need to remove the `'root','');` semi-colon after closing the round bracket as you are ending your statement there and than you are using OR operator

Comment: Try to use PDO or Mysqli the mysql functions ar deprecated from php version 5.0. Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `;` behind the `mysql_connect()`:

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
```

<sup>Besides, have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), as the `mysql_x` functions are deprecated!</sup>

Comment: oh yea ! Thanks man. Crazy how can i even forget it.. !

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); or  die(mysql_error());
```

after mysql_connect function change it to this

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or  die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); or  die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$objConnect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or  die(mysql_error());
                                                  ^ removed ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` from here

```
 'root',''); or  die(mysql_error());
           ^
```