# Trying to use a user-definied php variable in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY $teamval";

$result=mysql_query($SQL);

$num_results=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

$teamval is a value defined by a user, which is defined by selecting it in a dropdown list (The selections are all from a database)

What I'm getting is "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\processlvl1.php on line 44"

Any solutions?

Edit: the variable for $teamval is not a column, it's a variable in a column.

The database tables look something like this:

First Name              Last Name          Team
John                    Smith              ROH
Jake                    Harvey             ROH
Jerome                  Micheals           ANE

Basically trying to get it to output only the names paired with a certain team that is selected by the user

Comment: Is `$teamval` a correct database column?

Comment: You should use MySQLi in new code. [Explanation here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Comment: @DanielleZarcaro or PDO.

Comment: You wouldn't even be facing this problem if you'd use prepared statements.

Comment: Not exactly sure what prepared statements are, sorry man, only started learning this stuff last week and its for a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query return false if the request fail, not a resource. So meaby the error is your query.

try :

```
mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thay will explain to you what is wrong

Comment: Unknown column 'ANA' in 'order clause'

Comment: Not sure where it's getting 'order clause' from, but ANA is not a column, it's a variable in a column, so I guess I'm sorting it wrong?

Comment: so you are trying to order you result by a field that doen't exist (it is case sensitive)

Comment: Yes, the order must be focus on name of a column.

Comment: yeah, I guess. Basically 'ANA' is a team under the column of 'Team', but I just want it to display everyone on that team (Who is in another column called 'First_Name'). Is it just the way I wrote it wrong?