# PHP-mysql_fetch_array return nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I've trying to display values from mysql but it return any empty page. The connection is fine but it does not fetch the data from mysql. I tried all the answers from the similar questions asked. But nothing helped. Can somebody please help me? This is the code

```
    $con=  mysql_connect($host, $username, $pwd);

    if(!$con)
        die("not connected".  mysql_errno());

    echo(Connected);

    mysql_select_db("info",$con);

    $query="select * from people";

    $result=  mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['people_name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Oligatory "mysql is deprecated, use mysqli_* functions" comment. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: What is the error ? Actually `echo(Connected);` is an error !

Comment: I tried using mysqli too. It did not help.

Comment: I dont get any error. I just get a page saying Connected

Comment: Is this really saying connected? No error for undefined constant?

Comment: Nope. Are you saying the host, username and pwd?

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting the correct database?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried creating a new database and tried it.

Comment: Is there any way to check whether i am selecting the correct db and table? I mean like i must get an error if i dont select the correct db.

Comment: @Pradeep ,just check my answer..I have given 2 versions..You will get the answer

Comment: I presume he has error reporting set to off and hence when the script is terminating at `echo(Connected);` he is getting a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if your db user,password are correct! I test the code above :

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test"); // Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM people"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo $row['id'] . " -- " . $row['people_name']; echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

and give me the result without error: `10 -- JOHN 11 -- PRADEEP`

I just change `mysql_connect` to `mysqli_connect` add in `$con= mysql_connect($host, $username, $pwd);` a `dbname`. and `$con` become `$con= mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pwd,$dbname);` I use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. Here is a stackQuestion for the [mysql vs mysqli in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php) which can explain you the difference.

Comment: for me, doing `select *` did'nt show the result! I change `select column one by one` and was all ok. Perfectly show the result

Comment: Blindly fixing errors is not right. You should know what the error is before fixing it and you fixed it without knowing what is wrong. **The * is not wrong and it does not cause an error**.

Comment: Didn't throw any error, but didn't show any result! I have the same situation when i developed in PHP.

Comment: Yes. It has two records.

Comment: @Pradeep have you fix it?

Comment: @milaci no... still cant select the db

Comment: I don't understand why! The example above post from others is OK. I check this [mysql_select_db](http://it2.php.net/mysql_select_db) for any error but seems ok. A last try is to do a `select * from info.people`, because you don't see your db. Doing that if you connect to MySQL you should be able to execute the query above. Try that and let me now.

Comment: still getting the same error.. also the mysqli_error() does not display the error message..

Comment: Try to check if your db user,password are correct! I test the code above : `<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM people");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo $row['id'] . " -- " . $row['people_name'];
          echo "<br>";
          }
?>` and give me the result without error: `10 -- JOHN
11 -- PRADEEP`.

Comment: @Milaci Hey!!!!! it worked... Thanx a lot... i dont see any change in the code.. but how did it work???

Comment: I just change `mysql_connect` to `mysqli_connect` add in `$con=  mysql_connect($host, $username, $pwd);` a `dbname`. and `$con` become `$con=  mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pwd,$dbname);`. I use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. Here is a stackQuestion for the [mysql vs mysqli in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php) which can explain you the difference.

Comment: @Pradeep Nothing, it's a pleasure to help the community of stackoverflow but the legend says: if the answer is correct, vote it. So the other can see immediately the solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
     <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","info");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM people");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['people_name'];
          echo "<br>";
          }


        ?>

 OR

 <?php
            $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password");
            // Check connection
            if ($con)
              {
              echo "connected to db";
              }
            else
            {           
               echo "not connected to db";
           }
          $db_selected = mysql_select_db("info", $con);

          if (!$db_selected)
              {
           die ("Can\'t use info: " . mysql_error());
             }

            $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM people");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
              echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['people_name'];
              echo "<br>";
              }


            ?>
```

Comment: I get only an empty page.

Comment: @Pradeep ,I have given 2 codes..just check both of them

Comment: This is what i get. connected to dbCan\'t use test_db :

Comment: @Pradeep ,There is problem in your db probably..did u use `use yourdbname` after creating the db?.

Comment: @Pradeep ,now try executing the code which i mentioned..And tell what is happening

Comment: O/P is  -  connected to dbCan\'t use yourdb :

Comment: @Pradeep ,I have edited along with your db name..Check,it should work 100%

Comment: still geting connected to dbCan\'t use info:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
 $con=  mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');

    if(!$con)
        die("not connected".  mysql_errno());

    echo("Connected");

    mysql_select_db("test",$con);

    $query="select * from tabale_name";

    $result=  mysql_query($query,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: ,mysql is depriciating..dont appriciae others to use that ...Also your select query should be `select * from tablename` and not `dbname`

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. Anyway I create a test db and I test this code. It is working properly.