# login page nested if php

Tags: php, html, mysql

login php with different user by classified the code using nested if method, however, it will only run the first if but not the second

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id= '$id' AND password= '$password'");

$sql1 = "SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = ' $password'";    

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)

{
    if($sql1 = "student" )
```

where the nested if begin

```
    {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
        window.location.href='google.com.my'
        </SCRIPT>");

        }
        else if($sql1 = "lecturer" )**it will not run until this if **
    {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully123!.')
        window.location.href='www.yahoo.com'
        </SCRIPT>");

        }
            exit();
}
else{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Wrong username password combination.Please re-enter.')
        window.location.href='login.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
}   
?>
```

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks and you should **NEVER** store users passwords in plain text.

Comment: for a start, `if($sql1 = "student" )` is assignment not comparison, you need a `==`. Also, `$sql1` doesn't equal `student`.. there are many problems here

Comment: What @Alfie says, if you write `if(a = b)` it will give a the value of b. You should write `if(a == b)` which means it sees if those are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = ' $password'");
```

instead of

```
$sql1 = "SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = '$password'";
```

You have to `fetch` the data from table using `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`

And `if` condition should be

```
if($something == "student" )
```

not

```
if($something = "student" )
```

**EDIT**

Try like this..and make required changes

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = ' $password'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
   $result = $row['position'];
}
```

Then

```
if($result == "student")
{
  //do something...
}
```

Comment: after i changed all, it will show only blank page instead of showing the google or yahoo site. and it still stay in the php page.

Comment: sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id= '$id' AND password= '$password'");
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = ' $password'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
   $result = $row['position'];
}
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
 if($result == "student")
 {
 echo ('hi');
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
        window.location.href='google.com.my'
        </SCRIPT>");
 
  }
  else 
 {
  echo ('hi1 ');

Comment: and finally close two brackets at the end

Comment: same , it's still not working. i will run straight to if statement 2

Comment: Try the query seperately to make sure they are working. If the queries are working fine then go to each if condition in a step wise manner. Thanks for try :)

Comment: Sorry i still dont get it .

Answer (score 0):

In your second sql statement, change `' $password'";` to `'$password'";`

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing, but assigning value to `$sql1`

```
if($sql1 = "student" )
```

Change to

```
if($sql1 == "student" )
```

For password safety, use [`password_hash` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

You never run a query to return a value to $sql1.  put `mysql_query` around your $sql1 query and it'll return what you want.  Also you're not breaking out of your query to input data, you have to do `mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = "' . $id . '" AND password = "' $password'");`

Also you should move to mysqli_query rather than mysql_query. 
[MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)