# how to connect php with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am very new to php. I am trying to make a sign up page with php. So simple but I can't. I've searched across google how to connect it. They said below.

```
  <?PHP

  $user_name = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "user";
  $server = "127.0.0.1";

  mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

  print "Connection to the Server opened";

  ?>
```

I've successfully created my user database with full set of data in phpmyadmin. And running Apache and Mysql in control panel. I set the password in phpmyadmin and I changed it in $password="mypassword";. But there is no print on my web page. I think the above code is correct and I am having problems before this state. Such as the location of my database, I don't where to put it or just created on myadmin is fine. Thank you for reading my problem and kindly advice me for the beginner course.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: `mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: What protocol are you using to load the PHP program? HTTP? HTTPS?

Comment: What happens if you View Source in your browser?

Comment: I am creating it locally on localhost. HTTP .

Comment: So it says `localhost` in your browser's address bar?

Comment: For the love of everything good and beautiful in this world, there is **no good reason** to be using the deprecated **mysql** interface library. New development should be using either **mysqli** or **PDO**.  Anyone who provides an answer related to the `mysql_` functions is doing you a **grave** disservice.

Comment: no no . . sorry . My html path . . on desktop

Comment: Really, please start with some googling and PHP manual reading ...

Comment: `I changed it in $password="mypassword";` but in question you have kept the password as  `$password = '';`

Comment: when you type `localhost ` in ur browser what do you see?
can u take screen shot and attach it in question

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. that is I am just missing php basics. I got my access to database is successful. Thank you !

Comment: how ? what was the problem ? @user3517970

Comment: shamefully. I am working my webpage out of mysql access! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no no . . sorry . My html path . . on desktop

PHP, in this context, is a server side programming language. You must request the script from a server that will pass it through a PHP interpreter before sending it to the browser.

Type `http://localhost/etc/etc` into the browser's address bar. Don't open the PHP program directly in your browser (e.g. by double clicking the file in Windows Explorer).

Comment: Here is object not found error. you mean I have to export database to my web page directory?

Comment: @user3517970 — if you mean a 404 error, then you have to use the URL of your PHP script. `/etc/etc` was a placeholder example. The PHP file needs to be accessible to your webserver. The database server needs to be running on the IP address you specified in your PHP program.

Comment: I exported user.sql from phpmyadmin and put it to my signup webpage folder. Is this correct ?

Comment: @user3517970 — No. I just told you that you didn't have to do that. Your **PHP script** has to be accessible to your webserver. Your PHP script will communicate with your database server. Any export of your database is useful only for backup purposes.

Comment: sorry for my knowledge. you can point me a reference for a beginner guide. I am sorry.

Comment: thank you for your patient answering. However the answers of the others are skillful, you are the best trainer for beginners like me. Thank you so much. I got it !

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $user_name = "root";
  $password = "";
  $database = "user";
  $server = "127.0.0.1";
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password, $database );

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Try `mysqli` instead of `mysql` and here is [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Comment: While that is good advice, it doesn't solve the problem (see the comments on the question).

Comment: i thought this might help since he has not included error checking in his code !!!

Comment: Error checking won't help with the current problem since the PHP isn't being executed at all.

Comment: Sorry for my knowledge .

Comment: your codes successfully work. Thank you I am now connected. I've vote it up for you.

Comment: @user3517970 : if it answers your question , please accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use procedural style function calls with the **mysqli** interface:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','myuser','mypassword','mydb')
       or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

If you are going to use object oriented style with **mysqli** interface:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'mydb');
```

Reference:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

---

If you are going to use **PDO** interface

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', $user, $pass);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: While rewriting the code to use a modern MySQL API is good practise, this doesn't address the problem.

Comment: @Quentin: What this answer addresses is the question in the title of the question "how to connect php with mysql". It doesn't address the questions: "How do I start the webserver?", "How do I get the webserver to run a PHP script?", or "Why is my webserver responding with 404?" or "Why does hello_world.php page not display anything?" And I don't think I'm suggesting "rewriting code"; I'm suggesting that the OP write code that won't need to be rewritten later."

Comment: The idea is that you understand the actual problem and not simply literally answer the title.