# Switching on mysqli over mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql installed and now I want to work on mysqli with new database.

Does it affect my previous database which is in mysql if I enable mysqli in phpmyadmin?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 17):

**mysqli** -> **MySQL Improved Extension**.

> The mysqli extension, or as it is sometimes known, the MySQL improved extension, was developed to take advantage of new features found in MySQL systems versions 4.1.3 and newer. The mysqli extension is included with PHP versions 5 and later.

You just have to change the code you have done using `mysql`. No Need to change the database. `mysqli` methods also use the `mysql` database.

[This may help](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi)

Answer (score 7):

if you're switching from MySQL to MySQLi, 
I suggest you to go for PHP Data Objects (PDO) with Prepared Statements.

It could give you little bit of burden initially, but once you create your own PDO class, you will be so glad upon your PDO work, believe me.

I took help from below links when I started it. try'em.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: Although PDO is the right thing to do, this doesn't answer the question and should be written as a comment instead.

Comment: @Calimo, Agreed ! Actually, The reason to write this thing in ANSWER section was,  I wasn't able to comment before posting this answer !

Answer (score 0):

Before today I use to use `mysql` but today I changed to `mysqli`. Nothing happens if you use `mysql` no need to create a new DataBase for this.

The suggestion I would give is to use `mysqli` since it is

> Improved version of mysql and provides better functionalities

[This is one good SO post about difference between two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Other way is also to switch if you go to `PDO`