# How to create query by using php

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get list  after query by using php drop down list.
My code looks like this for now:

```
     $con = mysql_connect($server,$user_name,$password,$database);
     $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $con);
     if ($db_found) {
     print "Database Found ";
     }
     else {
     print "Database NOT Found ";
     }

     $result = mysql_query($con,$db_found,"SELECT
     connection_log.user,count(*)  
     as 'connection_count', sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
     connection_log.logondate,connection_log.logoffdate)) 
     as `connection_time`
     FROM connection_log 
     INNER JOIN users 
     ON connection_log.user=users.user WHERE users.groups 
     LIKE '%cpg_sirket_dyo%' 
     and connection_log.logondate>='2015-09-01 00:00:00' 
     and connection_log.logoffdate<'2015-10-01 00:00:00' 
     group by connection_log.user 
     order by connection_count desc");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
     echo $row['name']."<br />";  
     }
```

But when I run this php I get some error like shown below:

> Database Found PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 >given in /var/www/html/test.php on line 22
>   PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null >given in /var/www/html/test.php on line 23

Have you any idea?

Comment: update... mysql_query("SELECT ....",$con);

Comment: Don't you think the warning message is verbose enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**

> mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

Only need two parameter needed

1)Your query.

2)The MySQL connection

You just remove your database name inside your mysql_query **also swap position** of query and connection

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT....",$con);
```

> Use backtick in column and table name instead of quotes

Correct your qyery with

```
     SELECT
     connection_log.user,count(*)  
     as `connection_count`, sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
     connection_log.logondate,connection_log.logoffdate)) 
     as `connection_time`
     FROM connection_log 
     INNER JOIN users 
     ON connection_log.user=users.user WHERE users.groups 
     LIKE '%cpg_sirket_dyo%' 
     and connection_log.logondate>='2015-09-01 00:00:00' 
     and connection_log.logoffdate<'2015-10-01 00:00:00' 
     group by connection_log.user 
     order by connection_count desc
```

> Note:- mysql is deprecated instead use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Wrong, first the query, than the $con

Comment: yaa i know this is also mistake in OP question. but thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this $db_found out of your function :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
$result = mysql_query($yourQuery,$con);
```

Also try using mysqli instead of mysql which is deprecated.

[MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Comment: Wrong, first the query, than the $con

Comment: Yup typed too fast, edited now

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

There are only 2 parameters, the query and (optinal) the connection, so you have to use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...", $con);
```

Comment: If i got the sarcasm correct, I've just wanted do make this clear for the people who read this afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code,

```
$con = mysql_connect($server,$user_name,$password);
     $db_found = mysql_select_db($database);
     if ($db_found) {
     print "Database Found ";
     }
     else {
     print "Database NOT Found ";
     }

     $result = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY",$con);
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
     echo $row['name']."<br />";  
     }
```