# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, validation, xampp

need some help with the code below. This the part of a php code to check if the combination of the user ID and encrypted password are already in the database. So when I run the code with Xampp, an error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' occurred.

```
<?php
//Determine if the User ID and password are on file.
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $db_userid = $row->admin_id;
    $db_password = $row->admin_password;
    $name = $row->admin_name;

if($db_userid != $userid || $db_password != $encryptpasswd){

    //If not on file, add record to administrator table.
    $query = "INSERT INTO administrator(admin_id, admin_password, admin_name)
                VALUES('$userid','$encryptpasswd','$name')";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die("Insert to administrator failed." . mysql_error());

    //Return to adminAuthen.php
    header( "Location: adminAuthen.php");
}
else{
    //If on file, set the session variable, and enter site.
    $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
    $_SESSION["retry"] = "admit";
    $_SESSION["time"] = time();
    header( "Location: /ClassRegistration/Maintenance/systementry.php")
}
?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: in which line you got error?

Comment: Missing semi-colon on last header() line?

Comment: Did you even google the error?

Comment: @Mike 9 out of every 10 questions posted lately, most likely don't know what to punch into Google.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I know what you mean. But there's almost no way to put the *wrong* thing in the search box in this case.

Comment: @Mike Googling "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'" popped up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them as the 3rd result (page one) ;-) Google is such an efficient search "tool". It even rubs elbows with Stack ;-)

Comment: @Mike Plus, watch this. The OP's going to come back and tell everyone: *"It doesn't work"*. Gee, I wonder why(?). Or, just walk away without saying anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm putting my money on option 2...

Comment: @Mike *Yep!* GMTA ;-)

Comment: Do you know that your code will not work in PHP 7 (future version of PHP) and that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since a long time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `;` after this line `header( "Location: /ClassRegistration/Maintenance/systementry.php")`

The correct code should be:

`header( "Location: /ClassRegistration/Maintenance/systementry.php");`

**on a futher note:**
Please do not use mysql_query to connect to your database. This is very unsafe and will be removed in the next version of PHP. This means you code is going to break very soon.

Please look at the following page for more information: [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Apply a semi colon after header function

`header( "Location: /ClassRegistration/Maintenance/systementry.php");`