# Php to Excel : fill the output Excel file with a loop

Tags: php, excel, loops, counter

I want to create an Excel file (with PhpExcel) and fill it with the content of a MySQL query.

I only have one column so the result will look like this :

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $i, $content)
```

So I have to loop inside my query and create a counter to fill each row corresponding to each item of the column **ptlum** of my content.
So the goal is to have the following result :

```
1 AX001
2 AX003
3 AX012
```

The code is the one :

```
$column = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $workbook = new PHPExcel;
    $sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $column, $data['ptlum']);
    //echo($column. " "  . $data['ptlum']. " ");
    $column = $column + 1; //or $column++;
```

The problem is that my Excel file is empty..
If i put a number instead of $column in the *setCellValueByColumnAndRow* line it works. But the variable does not work..
On the other hand if I put "$column = 1;" inside the loop, my Excel file will always contain one only row..

Have you an idea ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the call to `setCellValueByColumnAndRow` for each column and increment it:

```
$sql = "SELECT ptlum FROM `ptlum` WHERE nomcom = 'AIGREFEUILLE' and RIGHT (date,4) < 2015 and RIGHT(date,4) > 0 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = 1; // 1-based index
$column = 1;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $data['ptlum']);
    $column = $column + 1; //or $column++; if you prefer
}
```

As you see, you can retrieve the field/column you want with `mysql_fetch_assoc`, returning an associative array.

Also, you don't have to include the field(s) of your `WHERE` condition(s) in the `SELECT`.

Then finally, you should replace the deprecated `mysql_*` function by their equivalents `mysqli_*`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php).

**Edit:**

For your "new" problem, this code should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT ptlum FROM `ptlum` WHERE nomcom = 'AIGREFEUILLE' and RIGHT (date,4) < 2015 and RIGHT(date,4) > 0 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = 1; // 1-based index
$column = 1;
$workbook = new PHPExcel;
$sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, $row, $data['ptlum']);
    $column = $column + 1; //or $column++; if you prefer
}
```

First, don't instanciate your workbook and sheet in each loop, do it before, once.

Second, you had your arguments in the wrong order, it's `column` then `row`, not the inverse, as explicited in the method name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have not the correct echo.. First my query is based on two fields (ptlum and RIGHT(date,4)) and I don't managed to get only the field ptlum in my echo.. I just want to increment **i** which is my column index (not row I'm sorry) and ptlum. I tried your snippet with an echo ($i . " " . $value. " ") but it does not work.. I have the following result: http://imagik.fr/images/2015/11/25/phpexcel.png

Comment: I have a result like 1 AA15 2 AA15 3 AA15 4 AA15 instead of 1 AA15 2 AA16 3 AA17 4 AA18. What's more the other field is written (DATE) whereas I only want the **ptlum** field.. Thanks !

Comment: @Julien look at my edit, is it what you wanted? The results are on one row.

Comment: @Julien look at the explainations I've added, it might help ;)

Comment: I'm sorry I have another problem.. The echo instruction works very well but the output Excel file is empty.. I updated my first message, could you take a look ? Thanks again Veve !

Comment: @Julien look at my edit, it should work. I suggest you to make another question instead of (almost) completely change your question the next time ;)

Comment: Ok I understand, it works thank you ! I'm sorry, next time I'll make another question. Thanks again !

Comment: @Julien no problem, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the thing you wanted:

```
$sql = "SELECT ptlum, RIGHT(date,4)  FROM `ptlum` WHERE nomcom = 'AIGREFEUILLE' and RIGHT (date,4) < 2015 and RIGHT(date,4) > 0 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $i, $i+1); //1-based index
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $i, $data['ptlum']);
    $i++;
}
```