# Send data into Mysql database from Get data

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I would like send data into my arduino in my server.
I work on my php page but I have a problem with my statement.

```
// Connect to MySQL
include('dbconnect.php');

$_ADPS  = null;

$_ADCO = $_GET['ADCO'];
$_OPTARIF = $_GET['OPTARIF'];
$_ISOUSC = $_GET['ISOUSC'];
$_BASE = $_GET['BASE'];
$_HCHC = $_GET['HCHC'];
$_HCHP = $_GET['HCHP'];
$_EJPHN = $_GET['EJPHN'];
$_EJPHPM = $_GET['EJPHPM'];
$_BBRHCJB = $_GET['BBRHCJB'];
$_BBRHPJB = $_GET['BBRHPJB'];
$_BBRHCJW = $_GET['BBRHCJW'];
$_BBRHPJW = $_GET['BBRHPJW'];
$_BBRHCJR = $_GET['BBRHCJR'];
$_BBRHPJR = $_GET['BBRHPJR'];
$_PEJP = $_GET['PEJP'];
$_PTEC = $_GET['PTEC'];
$_DEMAIN = $_GET['DEMAIN'];
$_IINST = $_GET['IINST'];
$_ADPS  = null;
$_IINST1 = $_GET['IINST1'];
$_IINST2 = $_GET['IINST2'];
$_IINST3 = $_GET['IINST3'];
$_IMAX = $_GET['IMAX'];
$_IMAX1 = $_GET['IMAX1'];
$_IMAX2 = $_GET['IMAX2'];
$_IMAX3 = $_GET['IMAX3'];
$_PMAX = $_GET['PMAX'];
$_PAPP = $_GET['PAPP'];
$_HHPHC = $_GET['HHPHC'];
$_MOTDETAT = $_GET['MOTDETAT'];
$_PPOT = $_GET['PPOT'];


// Prepare the SQL statement
//$_SQL = 'INSERT INTO `tbTeleinfo` (`DATE`, `ADCO`, `OPTARIF`, `ISOUSC`, `BASE`, `HCHC`, `HCHP`, `EJPHN`, `EJPHPM`, `BBRHCJB`, `BBRHPJB`, `BBRHCJW`, `BBRHPJW`, `BBRHCJR`, `BBRHPJR`, `PEJP`, `PTEC`, `DEMAIN`, `IINST`, `ADPS`, `IMAX`, `IINST1`, `IINST2`, `IINST3`, `IMAX1`, `IMAX2`, `IMAX3`, `PMAX`, `PAPP`, `HHPHC`, `MOTDETAT`, `PPOT`) VALUES(`' + $NOW() + '`, `'+ $_ADCO + '`, `' + $_OPTARIF + '`, `' + $_ISOUSC  + '`, `' + $_BASE + '`, `' + $_HCHC + '`, `' + $_HCHP + '`, `' + $_EJPHN + '`, `' + $_EJPHPM + '`, `' + $_BBRHCJB +  '`, `' + $_BBRHPJB + '`, `' + $_BBRHCJW + '`, ` ' + $_BBRHPJW + '`, `'+ $_BBRHCJR +'`, `' + $_BBRHPJR + '`, `' + $_PEJP + '`, `' + $_PTEC + '`, `' + $_DEMAIN + '`, `' + $_IINST + '`, `' + $_ADPS + '`, `' + $_IMAX + '`, `' + $_IINST1 + '`, `' + $_IINST2 + '`, `' + $_IINST3 + '`, `' + $_IMAX1 + '`, `' + $_IMAX2 + '`, `'+ $_IMAX3 + '`, `' + $_PMAX + '`, `' + $_PAPP + '`, `' + $_HHPHC + '`, `' + $_MOTDETAT + '`, `' + $_PPOT + '`)';
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tbTeleinfo (DATE, ADCO, OPTARIF, ISOUSC, BASE, HCHC, HCHP) VALUES( NOW() , '" + $_ADCO + "', '" + $_OPTARIF + "', '" + $_ISOUSC  + "', '" + $_BASE + "', '" + $_HCHC + "', '" + $_HCHP + "')";


// Execute SQL statement
mysql_query($SQL);
```

After I'm trying to showing my statement in html page :

echo $SQL;

But, The result is 0 and my database is always empty.

My URL with data is : 
http://martin-valentin.fr/teleinfo/add_data.php?$_ADCO=040422168851&$_OPTARIF=BASE&$_ISOUSC=30&$_HCHC=0&$_HCHP=0

Did you see my error ?

Thanks
V. MARTIN

Comment: is the user  authorized to connect to the database?

Comment: That is unbelievably insecure. I hope that you aren't using that in production.

Comment: If the user was not authorize to connect at the database, he will be write a message error? no? and yes after I will make post data ;)

Comment: connection : <?php
$MyUsername = "userNameDB";
$MyPassword = "PasswordDB";
$MyHostname = "Server";

$dbh = mysql_pconnect($MyHostname , $MyUsername, $MyPassword);
$selected = mysql_select_db("database",$dbh);
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you concatenate with `.` and not `+`. Your query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbTeleinfo (DATE, ADCO, OPTARIF, ISOUSC, BASE, HCHC, HCHP) VALUES( NOW() , '" . $_ADCO . "', '" . $_OPTARIF . "', '" . $_ISOUSC  . "', '" . $_BASE . "', '" . $_HCHC . "', '" . $_HCHP . "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

**dbconnect.php**

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $conn);
if(!$db_selected){
   die("Failed to select db");
}
echo "Seccessfully selected db";
```

You are in PHP. In PHP, dot operater is used to concatenate

**yourscript.php**

```
require_once "dbconnect.php";

$_ADPS  = null;

$_ADCO = $_GET['ADCO'];
$_OPTARIF = $_GET['OPTARIF'];
$_ISOUSC = $_GET['ISOUSC'];
$_BASE = $_GET['BASE'];
$_HCHC = $_GET['HCHC'];
$_HCHP = $_GET['HCHP'];
$_EJPHN = $_GET['EJPHN'];
$_EJPHPM = $_GET['EJPHPM'];
$_BBRHCJB = $_GET['BBRHCJB'];
$_BBRHPJB = $_GET['BBRHPJB'];
$_BBRHCJW = $_GET['BBRHCJW'];
$_BBRHPJW = $_GET['BBRHPJW'];
$_BBRHCJR = $_GET['BBRHCJR'];
$_BBRHPJR = $_GET['BBRHPJR'];
$_PEJP = $_GET['PEJP'];
$_PTEC = $_GET['PTEC'];
$_DEMAIN = $_GET['DEMAIN'];
$_IINST = $_GET['IINST'];
$_ADPS  = null;
$_IINST1 = $_GET['IINST1'];
$_IINST2 = $_GET['IINST2'];
$_IINST3 = $_GET['IINST3'];
$_IMAX = $_GET['IMAX'];
$_IMAX1 = $_GET['IMAX1'];
$_IMAX2 = $_GET['IMAX2'];
$_IMAX3 = $_GET['IMAX3'];
$_PMAX = $_GET['PMAX'];
$_PAPP = $_GET['PAPP'];
$_HHPHC = $_GET['HHPHC'];
$_MOTDETAT = $_GET['MOTDETAT'];
$_PPOT = $_GET['PPOT'];



$SQL = "INSERT INTO tbTeleinfo (DATE, ADCO, OPTARIF, ISOUSC, BASE, HCHC, HCHP) VALUES( NOW() , '" . $_ADCO . "', '" . $_OPTARIF . "', '" . $_ISOUSC  . "', '" . $_BASE . "', '" . $_HCHC . "', '" . $_HCHP . "')";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

if($result){
     echo "Inserted data";
} else {
     echo "Failed to insert".mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Oh yes it's true.... It's not my fault xD. I'm coding in C#  too. I've change my database connection. I have errors. I will change my information connection.

Comment: result is 'Failed to insert No such file or directory'

Comment: Can you print all yours $_GET params using printf. Did you get all params for insertion?

Comment: Yes I can print all my $_GET params and when I print my sql statement, i see correctly my information.

Comment: Please try to give this in code $result = mysql_query($SQL, $conn); where $conn is mysql connection param

Comment: It's resolve. In fact, in my connection, I was close my connection, so when I do the insert, the connection was close

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use mysqli instead of mysql_query, because in future mysql_*() will be removed. For more information: [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-in-php)