# PHP Insertion of data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I'm having a problem in inserting data to my database. I don't have any clues what's the error.

Here's my index:

```
<form id="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <button id="sub">Save</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>
```

And here's my `insert.php`:

```
include_once('db.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_users VALUES('$name', '$username', '$password')")){
    echo "Successfully Inserted";
} else {
    echo "Insertion Failed";
}
```

And my `db.php`:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db = mysql_select_db('neverstoplearning');
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are talking about?

Comment: How many columns does your table have?

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) (which is likely why your query is failing) and you need to [stop using mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @Typoheads there's no error, it's just returning "Insertion Failed"

Comment: DO NOT USE mysql_* .

Comment: Then use `mysql_error()` to find out what the error is

Comment: @KayVan exactly 3 bro

Comment: I would look at the following links; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons and very very importantly https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @Drudge why not sir?

Comment: mysql_* is depricated from PHP5 and removed in PHP7.

Comment: @Karlaxis because these function are deprecated. Use mysqli_* instead.

Comment: Did you really name a table `table_users` ?

Comment: @Typoheads where should I put that sir? I'm new at php.

Comment: @Karlaxis You could do `echo "Insertion failed: " . mysql_error();`

Comment: @apokryfos Exactly sir even the table structure I already check them.

Comment: To both your lines in `db.php`, add `or die(mysql_error());` behind them. In your other files, take a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) and add that to your code. You should also take a close look at your table, making sure that the names and types are correct.

Comment: @Typoheads it returns "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". I have 4 column in my table the id (which is auto-increment), name, username and password also.

Comment: i bet you have a column set to INT rather than VARCHAR

Comment: @Karlaxis If your table has 4 columns you need to provide 4 values OR 3 column names with 3 values.

Comment: @CodeGodie Yes sir, the id column is INT then the rest is VARCHAR any problem with that?

Comment: No problem.. and what are your VARCHAR length values?

Comment: @Karlaxis Then your issue is that you're trying to insert `$name` where the ID should be. Change your query to something like  `"INSERT INTO table_users (\`name\`, \`username\`, \`password\`) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password')"`

Comment: i've change my code to:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_users (name, username, password) VALUES('$name', '$username', '$password')")

from:
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_users VALUES('$name', '$username', '$password')");

and now it's perfectly fine. Thanks to all the response! You guys rocks!

Comment: @Qirel I agree, sounds promising.

Comment: As a side-note, `<button id="sub">Save</button>` shouldn't actually submit the form unless you use some funky JavaScript. You'll need a `type="submit"` for that. ;-)

Comment: @Karlaxis `name` is a reserved word in SQL, so you should use backticks around it: `\`name\`` :-) See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Qirel Okay sir i'll take note of that thanks again! cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the HTML form in a valid way like you use form but not a submit button as `type submit`.

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Save" name='submit_form'/>
</form>
```

Now when you click on he submit button its go for the page `insert.php` and from there you need to store your the `username`, `name` and password.

**insert.php**

For this part you need to follow some rules, Stay away from `SQL Injection`, follow what i share as a Note at the bottom. And must use a **isset submit** for doing all these thing.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_form']){
    include_once('db.php');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // use mysqli_* and the $conn string.
    if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO table_users VALUES('$name', '$username', '$password')")){
        echo "Successfully Inserted";
    } else {
        echo "Insertion Failed";
    }
}
```

**Note:**

> For the protection of SQL Injection must use `mysqli_escape_string`,
>   `mysql_real_escape_string`, `addslashes` , `md5`, `hash`.
>   and `mysql_*` now `Deprecated`, so start use of `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.