# How can parse xml service and insert in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, phpmyadmin, xml-parsing

I don't know PHP very well because I am android developer so please help me.
I have just trying to enter XML data into database using PHP. I have see other examples but don't get what can I do in my case.

**XML link :**  http://ca.sharmatutorial.com/ws.asmx/GET_Question_ByDate?dtDate=2016-03-17

**PHP Code:**
Here what can I define for retrieve and set data in database. I know below code not correct. please correct my for each loop for opt object and other also please check my sql query.

```
<!doctype HTML> 
  <html>
  <head>
  <?php  
  header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
  $mysqli = new mysqli ( 'localhost', 'mabhim92', '9993115300', 'gcm_chat');
    ?>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ca.sharmatutorial.com/ws.asmx/GET_Question_ByDate?dtDate=2016-03-17");

 $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, null, true)
     or die("cannot create");

foreach ($nodes->children() as $child)
{
$Ques_id= $child->id;
$Question= $child->text;
$Option_1= $child->opt;
$Option_2= $child->opt;
$Option_3= $child->opt;
$Option_4= $child->opt;
$Answer= $child->opt->ans;
$date= $child->date;
));
$sql = "INSERT INTO feeds (Ques_id, Question, Option_1, Option_2, Option_3, Option_4, Answer, date) VALUES('". $Ques_id."','". $Question."','". $Option_1."','". $Option_2."','". $Option_3."','". $Option_4."','". $Answer."','". $date."')";
mysql_query($sql);
 }
  ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**My database field:**

1   Ques_id = id

2   Question = text

3   Option_1 = opt (first obj in opts value)

4   Option_2 = opt (second obj in opts value)

5   Option_3 = opt (third obj in opts value)

6   Option_4 = opt (fourth obj in opts value)

7   Answer =  (which opt is ans=1)

8   date (timestamp) = date

Answer (score 0):

You have used **mysqli** syntax which is good. But at query execution time, you have used old **mysql_*** syntax which is wrong.

See this link:- [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)

**Suggestions**:-

1) You should check **connection error** as well as **query error** also.

2) If your query has outer **double quotes("")** then ther is no need of concatation. You can just add **single quote around your php variable**.

3) It is good practise to add **primary key** in your DB table.

4) Write connection object in body tag instead of header tag.

5) Always **ON** your error reporting in developement mode

```
<!doctype HTML> 
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<?php     
  header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
  $mysqli = new mysqli ( 'localhost', 'mab***', '99931***', 'gcm**');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://ca.sharmatutorial.com/ws.asmx/GET_Question_ByDate?dtDate=2016-03-17");

$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, null, true) or die("cannot create");

foreach ($nodes->children() as $child)
{
    $Ques_id= $child->id;
    $Question= $child->text;
    $Option_1= $child->opt;
    $Option_2= $child->opt;
    $Option_3= $child->opt;
    $Option_4= $child->opt;
    $Answer= $child->opt->ans;
    $date= $child->date;
//)); Typo error. No need for this line
$sql = "INSERT INTO feeds (Ques_id, Question, Option_1, Option_2, Option_3, Option_4, Answer, date) VALUES('$Ques_id','$Question','$Option_1','$Option_2','$Option_3','$Option_4','$Answer','$date')";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if (!$res) {
       printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
}

$mysqli->close(); // close connection
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: no its not my answer I want opt in loop because its multiple in opt node please see I need to parse and insert http://ca.sharmatutorial.com/ws.asmx/GET_Question_ByDate?dtDate=2016-03-17 this link