# php - how to exclude a line of code in a loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a code in HTML in a table. And I want the loop to just ignore them

```
<?php
$sel_admin = "query  ";
$rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
{      
    echo "<th>". $row['a'].  "</th>";


    </thead> // This two line of code
    <tbody>  // is the one I want to exclude in the while loop


    $sel_admin2 = "query2  ";
    $rs_admin2 = mysql_query($sel_admin2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin2))
    {
        echo" <tr class='gradeX'> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row2['sched3_time'].  "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Remove them from the loop?  If you delete the lines of code, they won't be executed.

Comment: I really can't remove them from the loop because the `<table>` needed it, for proper displaying of data

Comment: Then what exactly are you trying to do here?  You want them to be executed in the loop, but you don't want them to be executed in the loop?

Comment: I just like them to be as ease, like they won't be carried by the loop

Comment: What about showing an example of the output result you want to see?

Comment: Just access the first array element for the th and then do a for loop that will start from 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want those lines printed once, not to be outside the loop, per se. You could use a variable to track it:

```
$linesNeeded = true;
while (...) {
  ...
  if ($linesNeeded) {
    echo $line1;
    echo $line2;
    $linesNeeded = false;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your first loop, spit out the html and then start the loop again, havent tested but i think the below should now work.

```
 <?php
$sel_admin = "query  ";
$rs_admin  = mysql_query($sel_admin);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin)) {
    echo "<th>" . $row['a'] . "</th>";
}
?>
</thead> 
<tbody>
<?php
$sel_admin2 = "query2  ";
$rs_admin2  = mysql_query($sel_admin2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin2)) {
    echo " <tr class='gradeX'> ";
    echo "<td>" . $row2['sched3_time'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I already tried that, but the first `while` loop is important because it will increment so that the second query will move to the next column

Comment: Ok understood, difficult without knowing what your pulling from MySQL. I would amend your MySQL statement (if possible, probably is with JOINS) so that each row reflect a row in your table and you can loop just that. Nesting them just seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Please use mysqli instead of mysql. Take a look: [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)
+
Your problem's answer too.

```
<?php
     $sel_admin = "query  ";
     $rs_admin = mysqli_query($connection,$sel_admin);
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_admin))
     {      
        echo "<th>". $row['a'].  "</th>";

        ?>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

        $sel_admin2 = "query2  ";
        $rs_admin2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_admin2);
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_admin2))
        {      
           echo" <tr class='gradeX'> ";
           echo "<td>" . $row2['sched3_time'].  "</td>";
           echo"</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is honestly just a guess but based on the code you provided you actually need to add more code after remove the code you do not want:

```
<?php
$sel_admin = "query  ";
$rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
{      
    echo "<tr><th>". $row['a'].  "</th></tr>"; // Notice the <tr></tr>

    $sel_admin2 = "query2  ";
    $rs_admin2 = mysql_query($sel_admin2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin2))
    {
        echo" <tr class='gradeX'> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row2['sched3_time'].  "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
?>
```