# MySQL select region

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a simple Blog, at the first I read 6 records (Image + Title) and at the rest of them I want to read 7 through 10.
for 6 first I am using this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogcontents ORDER BY bid DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error Query [" . $sql . "]");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<li class="navblog"><a href="blogpage.php?id= ' . $row['bid'] . '"><div class="blogwrap"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive bphoto" src="images/blog/' . $row['btimg'] . '" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="300"><span class="sizeoftitle">' . $row['btitle'] . '</span></div></a></li>';
    }
```

But I don't know how can I read from 7 through 10.

[image]

Comment: Please update to the new MySQL driver - `mysqli`. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php) It's deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use limit and offset  (instead  the loop limitation) for retrieve  the rows you need
a firts select with 6 rows

```
"SELECT * FROM blogcontents ORDER BY bid DESC limit 6 ";
```

and a second select with the others 4 rows  starting form 5 (offeset is 0 based)

```
"SELECT * FROM blogcontents ORDER BY bid DESC limit 5,4 ";
```

or after your first loop retrive the others

```
 while (  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '<li class="navblog"><a href="blogpage.php?id= ' . $row['bid'] . '"><div class="blogwrap"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive bphoto" src="images/blog/' . $row['btimg'] . '" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="300"><span class="sizeoftitle">' . $row['btitle'] . '</span></div></a></li>';
 }
```

based  on your code in comment this should work

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * 
          FROM blogcontents
           LIMIT  5, 4"; 
           $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die("Error Query [" . $sql2 . "]");
```

and you don't need  for loop .. you can use while

```
while (  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 
          echo '<p><a href="blogpage.php?id= ' . $row['bid'] . '">' . $row['btitle'] . '</a></p>'; 
 } ?>
```

Comment: I alredy used before but it does not work, here you can see:

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM blogcontents LIMIT 4 OFFSET 6";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die("Error Query [" . $sql2 . "]");


for ($j = 0; $j < $num_rows-1; $j++)
 {
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
 echo '<p><a href="blogpage.php?id= ' . $row['bid'] . '">' . $row['btitle'] . '</a></p>';
 }
?>

Comment: as you see in the picture, the selected records again retrieve from the latest records! but I just want the rest of records...

Comment: I don't be able to read your language  for  me all the sign are same .. but try adjust the param for limit and offeset .. anyway i have update the asnwer  with some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

[Explain By Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLdpQ.jpg)

Please look at the picture I explained my question there...

Answer (score 0):

The result_array() function will format the mysql result into php array.

```
    function result_array($sql)
    {
        $result = array();
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $result[] = $data;
        }
        $rows = count($result);
        if ($rows) {
            $total_global_rows = count($result);
            $total_inner_rows = count($result[0]);
            $count_total_inner_rows = $total_inner_rows / 2;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $total_global_rows; $i++) {
                for ($j = 0; $j < $count_total_inner_rows; $j++) {
                    unset($result[$i][$j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blogcontents ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 10";

    $blogPosts = result_array($sql);

    //print till 6th and break the loop
    foreach ($blogPosts as $key => $row) {
        echo '<li class="navblog"><a href="blogpage.php?id= ' . $row['bid'] . '"><div class="blogwrap"><img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive bphoto" src="images/blog/' . $row['btimg'] . '" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="300"><span class="sizeoftitle">' . $row['btitle'] . '</span></div></a></li>';
        if ($key > 5) {
            break;
        }
    }

    //print from 7th to the end
    foreach ($blogPosts as $key => $row) {
        if ($key > 5) {
            echo $row['btitle'];
        }
    }
```