# localhost redirected you too many times php form

Tags: php

I was making a library system that if you logged in you will be redirected to the customer information.

```
<?php 

include('session.php');
include('dbcon.php');?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Library</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url(image/bg9.jpeg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    .style72 {
        font-size: 14;
        color: red;
        font-weight: light;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center"><img src="image/logo.png" width="133" height="151"></p>
    <br/>
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <?php include('head.php'); ?>           
    <br/><br/>  
    <table width="945" height="33" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td width="47" height="27">
                <div align="center">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="image/homeicon.png" width="34" height="35" border="0" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="137">
                <div align="center" class="style72">
                    <a href="member.php">PROFILE</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="137">
                <div align="center" class="style72">
                    <a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="117">
                <div align="center" class="style72">
                    <a href="faq.php">FAQs</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="123">&nbsp;</td>            
            <td width="123">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="126">
                <div align="center" class="style72">
                    <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my session.php

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("librarian", $connection);
session_start();// Starting Session

// Storing Session
$member_check=$_SESSION['member'];

// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
$ses_sql=mysql_query("select member_name from member where member_name='$member_check'", $connection);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$member_session = $row['member_name'];
if(!isset($member_session)){
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

I really do not know what is the problem here. I have already clear my cookies and history. But cannot run also have error. I am sorry, I don't know how to code php well. Anyone can help me? This is my project final.

Comment: Please update to the new MySQL driver - mysqli. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php) It's deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in 7.0

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I'm trying to point out errors in your code

I think data is not coming from the database , so the !isset() become true and it redirects to the index.php, but the session is already set . So you again come back to this page , again , no data from the database make you end up in a loop hence too many redirects.

You have to put session_start() on the top in the php tag

And use mysqli instead of mysql

Include dbcon.php before the session.php

Unset the session variable after you used it.

[this](https://www.google.com/amp/m.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL%3Famp%3D1) step by step article will help you to make a good login system, with increased security and all .

Comment: Check that article @shby