# Error in controller and can not send data form to mysql with php api

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to insert data from 2 forms to my database using the PHP API. But I got an error. Please help me to fix this.

**My form : testing_form.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Form Insert">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="cobaInsert" >
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="insertData()">
              Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**my controller : controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
.controller('cobaInsert',function($scope, $stateParams, $http){    
        $scope.insertData=function(){      
            $http.post('http://pvcmate.com/api/coba_form.php', {
                'username':$scope.username,
                'password':$scope.password
            }).then(function(response){
                    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                },function(error){
                    alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }
        });
```

**This is my php file : coba_form.php**

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
// $bname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->bname);
// $bauthor = mysql_real_escape_string($data->bphone);

$username = $data->username;
$password = $data->password;


mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("testing");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'coba_form'('','username','password')
    VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."') ") or die(mysql_error());
//echo $bname." ".$bphone;
?>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add model to `ng-click="insertData()"`.

Add `username` and `password` to `ng-click` like this `ng-click="insertData(username,password)"`

or make models like this `ng-model="something.username"`, `ng-model="something.password"` and add `something` to `ng-click` like this `ng-click="insertData(something)"`.

P.S. Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. - [More about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php).

Comment: Hello.. Im done change it with your recomend code. I insert data to 2 form and click submit but now the console have output like this : 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pvcmate.com/api/coba_form.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

What is that? Thanks..

Comment: @YosiaPrabowo Add CORS plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en to Chrome, enable it, and try again.

Comment: @tomyslav Amazing, its work well insert to my database. But after I click insert button, system store 2 data to database and username+password is null. Just id can inserted to my database.

Comment: @YosiaPrabowo  Did you change `mysql` to `mysqli`? And, do you get correct values in `insertData` function when console.log `username` and `password`?

Comment: Yes, I use mysqli. Its wrong? In log console I just get "Data Inserted Successfully" output..

Comment: sorry, in my question I read with mysql. Exactly I use mysqli in my program. I will write again in new answer. Thanks

Comment: @YosiaPrabowo Firstly, we need to evaluate if client side working properly. Try to console.log `$scope.username` and `$scope.password` inside `insertData()` function in controller.js to see if you get correct values that you entered in the form. P.S. You can edit your question and add your PHP there instead as answer.

Comment: still error. Is it possible if I have an error during the installation nodejs, and others? Because I had a problem on my url. Url my current http://192.168.1.8:8100/ and instead of http: // localhost: 8100 /

Answer (score 0):

This is my PHP

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
$kode_decode = file_get_contents("php://input")
$data = json_decode($kode_decode);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($data->username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($data->password);

//$foo= $_GET['first'];
//$foo1= $_GET['second'];

$host = "mysql.idhostinger.com";
$username_database = "";
$pass_database = "";
$database = "private";

$connect_db = mysqli_connect($host, $username_database, $pass_database, $database); 

if ($connect_db) {
    echo "Database ditemukan";
}else {
  echo "Database Tidak Ada";
  mysqli_close($connect_db);
}

$tesa = 'yosia';
$tesb = 'pazz';

$query = "INSERT INTO coba_form VALUES('','".$tesa."','".$tesb."')";
$sql = mysqli_query($connect_db, $query);

if($sql){
    echo "data berhasil di insert ke dalam database";
}else{
    echo "data gagal diinsert ke dalam database";
}
//mysql_select_db("300927381_smst");
/*$tesa = 'yosia';
$tesb = 'pazz';
$qry = 'INSERT INTO coba_form values ("''","'.$tesa.'","'.$tesb.'")';



$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);

if ($qry_res) {
    $arr = array('msg' => "User Created Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
} else {
    $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In inserting');
    $jsn = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($jsn);
}*/

?>
```

What is wrong? Thanks