# How can I use array to cut down this block of code by retrieve these captions from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So instead of caption1, caption2, caption3 etc, how am I able to just pull the caption from a DB? Probably simple but I'm fairly new so I apologize.

```
<?php
    $captions = array(
    /*01*/ "caption1",
    /*02*/ "caption2",
    /*03*/ "caption3",
    /*04*/ "caption4",
    ); 

    for($n = 1; $n <= count($captions); $n++):
?>
```

EDIT:
And yes I have a DB connected.

Here is my attempt at trying to retrieve the captions. Unfinished yet because I'm not to sure if I'm even going in the right direction.

```
<?php
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images_tbl");
            $array = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($array)){
            echo $row['caption'];
                        }


                $caption = array ( "");

                for($n = 1; $n <= count($caption); $n++):
            ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a db setup already? What is your code to retrieve your caption?

Comment: You should connect to the database first, you can use and ORM or plain PHP to do that. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Edited for more information on on my attempt

Comment: Looks like you answered your question already.

Comment: Although I'm getting:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallerywebsite\albums3.php on line 70

Comment: you can't mix different mysql apis and the base connection is unknown.

Comment: To be fair I could just search for an answer to that, seems to be a common mistake for newcomers.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php.

Comment: *"EDIT: And yes I have a DB connected."* - Being what, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other? Only you know that.

Comment: mysqli_, I corrected my mistake on my code, still no success nonetheless.

Comment: you need to stop editing *on the fly here*. I rolled the question back to a previous revision. You need to place a comment under the answer given as to what's not working.

Comment: Sorry, I'll just research it a bit more in depth with the sources localheinz has given me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code like this:

```
// establish database connection with your credentials
$connection = mysqli_connect(
    $host,
    $user,
    $password,
    $database
);

// query database
$result = mysqli_query(
    $connection,
    'SELECT caption FROM images_tbl'
);

$captions = [];

// check if querying succeeded
if (false !== $result) {
    // populate captions with values from database
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $captions[] = $row['caption'];
    }
}
```

**Note** Adjusted your query to select `caption` only instead of all columns, and consistently used `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: you missed the connection to the query function, and we don't even know if they did connect and which api is used.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha, good point! Adjusted it.

Comment: see my (last) comment under the question about their edits. I think you're / we're in for a long ride.

Comment: Sorry Fred, won't be a "long ride" today :(

Thanks for the help localheinz, you're a true beast. Have a nice day.