# Can't send data to database

Tags: php, html, sql

How can I solve this error?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user','pass') VALUES('','')' at line 1

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOc0E.png)

```
<?php 
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('can not connect to server'.$conn->connect_error);
if($con)
{
    mysql_select_db('mydb',$con) or die ('can not seletc the database'.$conn->connect_error);
}
$error ='';
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];     

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblogin('username','password') VALUES('$username','$password')");
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    if($id > 0)
    {
        $error .= "Register Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        $error.="Fail To Register<br>".mysql_error();
    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <h2>POS Register</h2>
        <h5 style="color: red;"> <?php if(isset($error)){echo $error;} ?> </h5>   
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>User Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
                         <a href="login.php">Back To Login</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using single quotes it\s need to be " ` ".

Comment: kindly will you mention that line , its help me a lot. I've been stuck here for a long time۔ Please !

Comment: @BĩğrăyŇăwăb, try my solution

Answer (score 1):

In my concern , it's advisable to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` since it's been deprecated also , you can know more about it here :- [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)

To your problem, the answer is :

```
   $mysql_query = "INSERT INTO tblogin(username,password) values ('$username','$password')";
   $result = mysql_query($mysql_query);
```

To detect if it's successfully inserted :

```
if($result)
{
echo "Success";

}
else
{
echo "Error";

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,its working , kindly give me one more favour , point the mistake, which i have make ... I;m very thankful to you !

Comment: You were using single quotes with your column names which is not neded.

Comment: @BĩğrăyŇăwăb, what's the other favor you need?

Comment: @Sand, his structure could be varchar , so it's best to put a single quote for username and password IMHO . Most developer treat it as varchar.

Comment: Yeah this is never an issue with `PDO` or `mysqli_` I'm so rusty with `mysql` now.

Comment: @BĩğrăyŇăwăb, i've also added a method to detect if it fail to insert it will throw and error, i've updated both of my answer.

Comment: @FreedomPride Thanks a lot sir, its working..!

Comment: @BĩğrăyŇăwăb, feel free to upvote my answer :D and press the tick button on my answer if it helps

Comment: ohh definitely, actully , thats my first question on this form , so dont know about much, thats the reason till i doesn't mark this ,now i done ....once again thanks a lot

Comment: Hey , Will you give me a one favour please :(

Comment: @Newbiee, sure how can i help you with?

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblogin('username','password') VALUES('$username','$password')");
```

To this

```
mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO tblogin(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')");
```

or

```
mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO tblogin(username,password) VALUES('".$username."','".$password."')");
```

Above will run the query but if you do like this,

```
$results = mysql_query($con, "INSERT INTO tblogin(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')");
```

You can check if the query got executed successfully using an `if ... else` like this,

```
it($results){
  echo "Query execution done";
}else{
  echo "Query execution didn't happen";
}
```

**IMPORTAN**
It's better to drop using `mysql` because it has been deprecated and in the new PHP versions it has been removed so it's better to pickup on `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

`mysqli_` is the and improved version of `mysql_` it's pretty similar to `mysql` but has more security against SQL Injection security threat.

`PDO` which stands for PHP Document Object is another interface and very good one to be used with PHP and data bases. Personally I like `PDO` it's kind of universal not like `mysqli_` which is manly for MySQL and for me prepared statements are much easier in `PDO`.

You can do your own research and make the switch drop the use of `mysql`

- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
- [`mysqli` prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [`PDO` prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [`PDO` vs `mysqli`](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/521-mysqli-vs-pdo-vs-mysql.html)

Comment: Thanks , for help me out but it still giving the same error !

Comment: I updated my answer it had an error.

Comment: sand, both wil not working , but fredompride answer is working, will you explain this please , why its not working ?

Comment: It's not working because your query is not getting executed look at your `mysql_query` and the answer from  fredompride. In his answer his binding the SQL to a variable then calling it using the `mysql_query`. I also over looked it but I'll correct it. Also you should up vote and mark the answer as selected to show that answer solved your problem.

Comment: ah I think you marked the wrong answer as the selected :P.

Comment: mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tblogin(username,password) values ('$username','$password')");

the working one is that...

thanks a lot to help me out!

so edit your answer in that way

Comment: oh ok I'll edit it

Comment: Hey , Will you give me a one favour please :(