# Error while accessing MySQL resultset

Tags: mysql, fetch

When I executed this code,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

there was an error of the following plan:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in String of treatment:while($row =
>   mysql_fetch_array($res))

Comment: English please.. and please provide your code already tried

Comment: There was an error of the following plan: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

String of treatment:while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))

Comment: show your all code, not just while, edit your post, and mysql is also deprecated, please use PDO or mysqli, you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: These extensions are already in use. PCP version 5.6.33.

Piece of query: $query = 'SELECT Title,Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,Key6,ID,Ans FROM `ucp_tests` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10';
       $res = mysql_query($query);
       $i = 0;
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       {

How to present it for new extensions?

Answer (score 1):

`$res` should be an resource , for example

`$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table;");`

after that only use `mysql_fetch_array`. Just for information
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: $res = mysql_query($query);
       $i = 0;
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       {

Answer (score 1):

Would be better to use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/549000/3179389) and this [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) about differences between them. So I advice you to use `mysqli`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT id, name FROM some_table');

if($result){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
           //extract values from row
           $id = $row['id'];
           $name = $row['name'];
     }
 }
```