# Fatal Error: Uncaught error Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() HTML/PHPMYADMIN

Tags: html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently stocked :( basically I am doing a login page There is no problem with the login page but once i submit it... this is my code for my login page.

```
<form action= "process.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" id="user" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
```

now my process.php however is making the same error..I cant seem to find the problem. Please Help Here is the code

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    //to prevent sql injection
    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string ($password);

    //connect to the server and select database
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("franklin offshore");

    //query the database for user
    $result = mysql_query("select * from login where username='$username' 
    and password='$password'")
        or die ("Failed to query database ".mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
    {
        echo "LOGIN SUCCESS WELCOME" .$row['username'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to LOGIN" ;
    }
?>
```

This is what it keeps showing

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_real_escape_string()

Please help

Comment: Most like your hosting uses PHP 7, and mysql_* extension has been completely removed from PHP 7. Also, Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: how can i know if im using php 7..however i have an phpMyAdmin 4.8.3

Comment: If you are on linux, go to terminal and type `php -v` and press enter. You will get the PHP version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `mysqli` (replace `mysql` with `mysqli` in your code) and to connect to your database with a variable.

Like this:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "", "database");
```

Then you have to put `$db` in your `mysqli_query` as a parameter.

Here is an example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "select * from login where username='$username' and password='$password'");
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! You are a life saver

Comment: I need to ask though, If i press my submit button even if the field is blank it still directs u to the site . How do i secure it?

Comment: @KimAleah Yes is directs you to the side, but if you want that the input fields are required just add `required` to your HTML input tag. Like this: `<input type="text" id="user" name="username" required>` Now the submit button directs you only, if the input has a text inside.

Comment: you really are a life saver

Comment: i can see that and you are younger than me...i feeel so bad now ^_^

Comment: can people message here?

Comment: Yes people can message here :)

Comment: how..cause i kinda need more help

Comment: @KimAleah Tell me your problem and I will try to solve it :)

Comment: is there no dm here?

Comment: @KimAleah I am sorry, but what do you mean with dm? :)

Comment: means to chat privately its direct message

Comment: @KimAleah No, thats not possible :(

Comment: @KimAleah And then I will look for it and answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below... It will work.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","franklin offshore");

$result = mysqli_query($db, "select * from login where username = '$username' and password = '$password'")
                or die("Faild to query database " .mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username']== $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    echo "Login success!!! Welcome " .$row['username'];
} else {
    echo "Faild to login!";
}

?>
```

As someone mention in above you need to replace all the mysql with mysqli in your code.

Please refer this link [MySQL vs MySQLi when using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php][1])

And also remove "mysql_real_escape_string" code also.

Thank you.